# Create a new matrix from indices

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

I have huge n×n matrix `A`, and the indices of its non-zero elements by `a = find(A)`. I have obtained a new list `a1` by deleting some elements from `a`. I want to have matrix `A` of indices in `a1` without using loops. Any suggestions? Is there any function for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that your matrix is "huge" (and your question implies that it is mostly zeroes), perhaps it would be best if you represent it as a [*sparse matrix*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix):

```
[ii, jj] = ind2sub(size(A), a1);
spA = sparse(ii, jj, A(a1), size(A, 1), size(A, 2));
```

There might be a significant speedup when operating on sparse matrices. If you need to obtain the full matrice back, use [`full`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html):

```
newA = full(spA);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use vector indexing. Without really knowing how "huge" is your matrix `A`, but assuming you can still handle it in one piece in matlab's memory, just:

```
B(size(A,1),size(A,2))=0;
B(a1)=A(a1);
```

Now `B` is the same as `A` with only the indexes given by `a1`.

Comment: You should either verify that there is no matrix `B` larger than `A` before running this code, or initialize it explicitly, _e.g_: `B = zeros(size(A));`.

Comment: if `A` is bigger than say 1000x1000, the initialization I wrote will work faster than the explicit `B = zeros(size(A));`. Choosing `B` assumes no previous matrix named `B` present, I thought that was evident...

Comment: I know that would work faster, we had a [long discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169222/faster-way-to-initilize-arrays-via-empty-matrix-multiplication-matlab) about that, remember? :) What I meant was that you need to make sure that the size of the initialized matrix `B` is correct. P.S: how do you know that `a1` is logical? Did you mean _vector indexing_?

Comment: yes, I meant vector indexing... thanks for noticing, I'll edit the answer. How can `B(size(A,1),size(A,2))=0;` be of different size than `A` ? what am I missing?

Comment: Well, if `B` already exists, and say, it's twice the size of `A`, then what you're doing is simply setting one element in `B` to zero instead of resetting the entire matrix. You need to clear `B` before doing this.