# Fastest variable-size array initialization in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization

In MATLAB, I am taking as an input `z`, an array of arbitrary size.  I now wish to create an array `w` with the same dimensions of `z`, but whose value's are everywhere `k`, some real number.  Here are two ways I thought of doing so:

```
z = rand(1000,1000); % pretend the size of z is not known beforehand
k = 2.3;

w = ones(size(z))*k;
w = zeros(size(z)) + k;
w = z - z + k;
```

I tried to see which of these methods would be fastest, and was quite surprised at the result:

```
tic; for n = 1:1000, w = ones(size(z))*k; end; toc
tic; for n = 1:1000, w = zeros(size(z)) + k; end; toc
tic; for n = 1:1000, w = z - z + k; end; toc

Elapsed time is 7.243662 seconds.
Elapsed time is 4.770328 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.750093 seconds.
```

Even more surprising was that for `k = 1` (where one would presume `ones()` would be the fastest)

```
tic; for n = 1:1000, w = ones(size(z)); end; toc
tic; for n = 1:1000, w = z - z + 1; end; toc

Elapsed time is 4.856666 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.759324 seconds.
```

My question is, then, are my results here correct?  If so, is `w = z - z + k` the fastest way of initializing an array of `k`'s, or is there better still?

Comment: This is either platform and/or version-dependent. On R2012b, OS X, the methods based on `ones` and `zeros` are actually twice as fast as your third method. See [this](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance/) if you want to try some other schemes.

Comment: I would recommend against your third method, if `z` contains a `NaN` or `Inf` somewhere the result will be a mess.

Answer (score 1):

If you look hard enough, you'll find a lot more obscure ways to initialize arrays.

For example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169222/faster-way-to-initilize-arrays-via-empty-matrix-multiplication-matlab) for a really unexpected one.

If you want to choose between them for speed, you will need to compare timings for a range of sizes for `z`, not just 1000x1000, as they will all scale quite differently (and likely not even monotonically, as MATLAB will suddenly switch to different memory allocation methods when the array reaches some threshold size). I just tried out your three methods, and at smaller sizes I find that the first is much faster than the second.

As @horchler mentions, timings will also be dependent on the MATLAB version, OS, processor cache size etc.

Comment: +1 for the reference, still hope that we find a quicker way to assign than the default method.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a faster way still is

```
w = zeros(size(z,1),size(z,2)) + k;

tic; for n = 1:1000, w = zeros(size(z,1),size(z,2)) + k; end; toc
Elapsed time is 2.120249 seconds.
```

although it beats me as to why.

Comment: Are you sure it is faster, for me the measurements are still all over the place with `n = 1000`

Answer (score 0):

One basic method that should not be forgotten (and is fairly quick as well):

```
w=repmat(k,size(z));

tic; for n = 1:1000, w=repmat(k,size(z)); end; toc
```

I usually go with this or `zeros(size(z))+k`