# MATLAB: Faster pre-allocation of zeros-matrix

Tags: matlab, loops, memory-management

**/edit**: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169222/faster-way-to-initilize-arrays-via-empty-matrix-multiplication-matlab) for an interesting discussion of the topic. Thanks @Dan

---

Using `a(m,n) = 0` appears to be faster, depending of the size of matrix `a`, than `a = zeros(m,n)`. Are both variants the same when it comes to pre-allocation before a loop?

Comment: You're right, I seem to have searched for the wrong keywords. Thank you. Will edit my main post in a few minutes, I'm on mobile right now.

Comment: See also [this](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance/) for more on preallocation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are definately not the same.

Though there are ways to beat the performance of `a=zeros(m,n)`, simply doing `a(m,n) = 0` is not a safe way to do it. If any entries in `a` already exist they will keep existing.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169222/faster-way-to-initilize-arrays-via-empty-matrix-multiplication-matlab) for some nice options, also consider doing the loop backwards if you don't mind the risk.

Comment: Looping backwards seems interesting, I will try that. Apart from when `a` already exists, why else would `a(m,n)` not be safe? Am I safe to use `clear a; a(m,n) = 0;` for preallocation (ignoring the fact that using clear makes it slower again)?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on your m and n. You can check the time for yourself

```
tic; b(2000,2000) = 0; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.004719 seconds.
tic; a = zeros(2000,2000); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.004399 seconds.

tic; a = zeros(2,2); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.000030 seconds.
tic; b(2,2) = 0; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.000023 seconds.
```

Comment: Hmm that's a much smaller difference than what I experienced. I may have made a mistake in my benchmark. Will check once I'm back in my office.

Comment: I wouldn't bet the farm on any timings measured in milliseconds on a PC.

Comment: As m and n increase you can see the difference. This is just an example.

Comment: I have indeed found a small mistake in my benchmarks, but I can reproduce what you wrote. It appears to be highly dependent on my matrices size. Dan posted a link to an interesting discussion with more in depth benchmarks. Thank you for your answer, Pavan.

Comment: `zeros` may depend on the number of elements *and* for sufficiently large allocations [how many threads](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/maxnumcompthreads.html) Matlab supports on your computer.

Comment: I think by default it takes advantage of the multithreading unless you turn it off. Anyway I have a i7 CPU 860 @ 2.80GHz × 8!