# improve loop performance in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, optimization, vectorization

Is there any way to improve performance with this kind of operation?

```
t=0:0.01:100;
f=@(t,l) exp(-t.*l)
l=[0.1:0.5:100];
for ll=1:length(l)
    a(ll,:)=f(t,l(ll));
end
```

I cannot think of any way to avoid the loop in these cases.

Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about good ol' matrix multiplication?

```
a = exp(-l.'*t);
```

Comment: of course... +1 I wonder whether bsxfun is still faster though.

Comment: @Daniel On my computer, for two input vectors of length 3000, this solution is about 4 times faster (0.7s for your solution, 0.175s for this one).

Comment: Can you provide some reference about the use of the combination of symbols  A.'*B please?

Comment: @Vaaal: for `.'` check `doc transpose`, for `*` check `doc mtimes`.

Answer (score 4):

```
t=0:0.01:100;
l=[0.1:0.5:100];
b=bsxfun(@(a,b)exp(-a.*b),t,l.')
```

For the simple case using a row and a column vector, bsxfun evaluates all combinations in a matrix.

---

Update:

It is possible to increase the speed by a factor of about 4 using `bsxfun` with `times`. This is faster because there is a highly optimized implementation for `bsxfun` for some basic math operations.

```
t=0:0.01:100;
l=[0.1:0.5:100];
b=exp(bsxfun(@times,-t,l.'))
```

---

Third solution, very simple and nearly as fast as my improved or natas solution. Simply preallocate `a`

```
t=0:0.01:100;
f=@(t,l) exp(-t.*l)
l=[0.1:0.5:100];
a=nan(numel(l),numel(t));
for ll=1:length(l)
    a(ll,:)=f(t,l(ll));
end
```

Matlab should have marked the line `a(ll,:)=f(t,l(ll));` with a yellow warning in the editor, it's worth reading them. If you click on it, preallocating is explained.

Comment: First, +1 on bsxfun, I always enjoy that people spread the word. Second, a faster preallocation will be `a(numel(l),numel(t))=0;` since prealocation also takes time, you can see how this changes the outcome of the overall performance. See here for a deeper discussion...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169222/faster-way-to-initialize-arrays-via-empty-matrix-multiplication-matlab

Comment: @natan: Never thought it would be possible to improve preallocation using `zeros` or `nan`. I'm reading it, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using meshgrid:

```
[t l]=meshgrid(0:0.01:100,0.1:0.5:100);
c=exp(-t.*l);
```