# MATLAB spending an incredible amount of time writing a relatively small matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a small MATLAB script (included below) for handling data read from a CSV file with two columns and hundreds of thousands of rows. Each entry is a natural number, with zeros only occurring in the second column. This code is taking a truly incredible amount of time (hours) to run what should be achievable in at most some seconds. The profiler identifies that approximately 100% of the run time is spent writing a matrix of zeros, whose size varies depending on input, but in all usage is smaller than 1000x1000.

The code is as follows

```
function [data] = DataHandler(D)
n = size(D,1);
s = max(D,1);
data = zeros(s,s);
for i = 1:n
    data(D(i,1),D(i,2)+1) = data(D(i,1),D(i,2)+1) + 1;
end
```

It's the `data = zeros(s,s);` line that takes around 100% of the runtime. I can make the code run quickly by just changing out the s's in this line for 1000, which is a sufficient upper bound to ensure it won't run into errors for any of the data I'm looking at.

Obviously there're better ways to do this, but being that I just bashed the code together to quickly format some data I wasn't too concerned. As I said, I fixed it by just replacing s with 1000 for my purposes, but I'm perplexed as to why writing that matrix would bog MATLAB down for several hours. New code runs instantaneously.

I'd be very interested if anyone has seen this kind of behaviour before, or knows why this would be happening. Its a little disconcerting, and it would be good to be able to be confident that I can initialize matrices freely without killing MATLAB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call to `zeros` is incorrect.  Looking at your code, `D` looks like a `D x 2` array.  However, your call of `s = max(D,1)` would actually generate another `D x 2` array.  By consulting the documentation for [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html), this is what happens when you call `max` in the way you used:

> `C = max(A,B)` returns an array the same size as `A` and `B` with the largest elements taken from `A` or `B`. Either the dimensions of `A` and `B` are the same, or one can be a scalar.

Therefore, because you used `max(D,1)`, you are essentially comparing every value in `D` with the value of 1, so what you're actually getting is just a copy of `D` in the end.  Using this as input into `zeros` has rather undefined behaviour.  What will actually happen is that for each row of `s`, it will allocate a temporary `zeros` matrix of that size and toss the temporary result.  Only the dimensions of the last row of `s` is what is recorded.  Because you have a very large matrix `D`, this is probably why the profiler hangs here at 100% utilization.  Therefore, each parameter to `zeros` must be **scalar**, yet your call to produce `s` would produce a **matrix**.

What I believe you intended should have been:

```
s = max(D(:));
```

This finds the overall maximum of the matrix `D` by unrolling `D` into a single vector and finding the overall maximum.  If you do this, your code should run faster.

As a side note, this post may interest you:

[Faster way to initialize arrays via empty matrix multiplication? (Matlab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169222/faster-way-to-initialize-arrays-via-empty-matrix-multiplication-matlab)

It was shown in this post that doing `zeros(n,n)` is in fact slow and there are several neat tricks to initializing an array of zeros.  One way is to accomplish this by empty matrix multiplication:

```
data = zeros(n,0)*zeros(0,n);
```

One of my personal favourites is that if you assume that `data` was **not declared / initialized**, you can do:

```
data(n,n) = 0;
```

---

If I can also comment, that `for` loop is quite inefficient.  What you are doing is calculating a 2D histogram / accumulation of data.  You can replace that `for` loop with a more efficient [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) call.  This also avoids allocating an array of `zeros` and `accumarray` will do that under the hood for you.

As such, your code would basically become this:

```
function [data] = DataHandler(D)
data = accumarray([D(:,1) D(:,2)+1], 1);
```

`accumarray` in this case will take all pairs of row and column coordinates, stored in `D(i,1)` and `D(i,2) + 1` for `i = 1, 2, ..., size(D,1)` and place all that match the same row and column coordinates into a separate 2D bin, we then add up all of the occurrences and the output at this 2D bin gives you the total tally of how many values at this 2D bin which corresponds to the row and column coordinate of interest mapped to this location.