# How can I put margins in an image?

Tags: matlab, matrix, binary-image

I have a binary image of 18x18 pixels and I want to put margins around this image with the purpose of obtaining an image 20x20 pixels.

[image: Description of the problem]

The image is binary and it can be represented by a matrix of 1s and 0s. The 0 pixels are in black colour and the 1 pixels are in white colour. I need to put margins of 1 pixel of zeros around the image that I have.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's get hackish:

```
%// Data:
A = magic(3);                 %// example original image (matrix)
N = 1;                        %// margin size

%// Add margins:
A(end+N, end+N) = 0;          %// "missing" values are implicitly filled with 0
A = A(end:-1:1, end:-1:1);    %// now flip the image up-down and left-right ...
A(end+N, end+N) = 0;          %// ... do the same for the other half ...
A = A(end:-1:1, end:-1:1);    %// ... and flip back
```

Comment: thanks! It is the most efficient solution. In my machine,the elapsed time by this method is approximately 10 times less than the method with the padarray function :D

Comment: Great! Yes, implicit zero-filling [has a name](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance/) for [being fast](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14195309/2586922) in Matlab

Answer (score 3):

The [`padarray`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html) function from the image processing toolbox can be used for this purpose:

```
B=padarray(A,[1,1])
```

Comment: Always there's some built-in doing exactly what I thought up independently. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

```
A=ones(18,18);%// your actual image
[M,N] = size(A);
B = zeros(M+2,N+2);%// create matrix
B(2:end-1,2:end-1) = A; %// matrix with zero edge around.
```

This first gets the size of your image matrix, and creates a zero matrix with two additional columns and rows, after which you can set everything except the outer edges to the image matrix.

Example with a non-square matrix of size `[4x6]`:

```
B =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

First make a matrix of 20 by 20 zeroes, `Zimg`, then insert your image matrix into the matrix of zeroes:

```
Zimg(2:end-1,2:end-1)=img;
```

Comment: Ok, same answer as Adriaan, who beat me to it.