# Taking alternatively elements of two vectors and compose them in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

Could you help me to write down a very fast algorithm in Matlab that does the following: I have `2` vectors, `A` of dimension `nx1` and `B` of dimension `nx1`. I want to construct `C` of dimension `2nx1` such that

```
C(1)=A(1), C(2)=B(1), C(3)=A(2), C(4)=B(2), C(5)=A(3), C(6)=B(3), ...
```

I though about

```
C=[];
for j=1:n
    C=[C; [A(j) B(j)]'];
end
```

Do you know something faster and more efficient?

Example:

```
n=9
A=[1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17]';
B=[2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18]';
C=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18]';
```

Comment: Didn't you want a *fast* answer? I have added a benchmark showing relative performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In matlab, index operations are generally faster than for-loops.
What I would do is first construct a `2nx1` matrix and then use indexing to assign the values:

```
C = zeros(2*n,1);
C(1:2:end) = A;
C(2:2:end) = B;
```

Comment: Initiallizing `c` with `c(2*n,1) = 0` is even faster (although admittedly hackish)

Comment: Interesting... didn't know that.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14195309/2586922) and the linked post @ThP

Comment: @LuisMendo It seems that this may not be the case anymore with the new execution engine in 2015b

Answer (score 5):

Typically you will want to avoid appending data to an array within a loop like you have written it as this has to re-allocate memory *every* time through the loop as you expand the variable.

The easiest thing to do would be to convert them both to row vectors using `(:).'`, concatenate them along the first dimension, and then flatten to a column vector using `reshape`. Because of MATLAB's column-major ordering, this will automatically inter-leave the values of `A` and `B` to create `C`.

```
C = reshape(cat(1, A(:).', B(:).'), [], 1)
```

## Benchmark

As far as whether this is faster than indexing (@ThP's answer), here is a brief test to benchmark the two.

```
sizes = round(linspace(100, 10000, 100));

times1 = zeros(size(sizes));
times2 = zeros(size(sizes));

for k = 1:numel(sizes)
    A = rand(sizes(k), 1);
    B = rand(sizes(k), 1);

    times1(k) = timeit(@()combine1(A,B));
    times2(k) = timeit(@()combine2(A,B));
end

figure
plot(sizes, times1)
hold on
plot(sizes, times2)
legend('cat + reshape', 'Indexing')

function C = combine1(A, B)
    C = reshape(cat(1, A(:).', B(:).'), [], 1);
end

function C = combine2(A,B)
    C = zeros(2*numel(A),1);
    C(1:2:end) = A;
    C(2:2:end) = B;
end
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. It would be interesting to compare using `C(2*n,1)=0` as suggested by Luis Mendo

Comment: @ThP I compared it. Hardly any difference.http://i.imgur.com/1DqE2gc.png

Comment: It is just micro optimization, but the following is slightly faster `    C = [A(:).'; B(:).']; C = C(:);` The guess is that it is just a function call (since the different is about constant relative to "cat + reshape"), but if the problem consists of many function calls it may be significant.