# How often does picking up junk data from malloc() occur

Tags: c, memory, malloc

In C I understand that by using `malloc()` you can occasionally allocate memory that contains some junk data if you never used `memset()` or used `calloc()` instead.

How often does picking up junk data occur?

Is there a safe way to avoid this without having to use `calloc()` or `memset()` every single time?

Comment: Uninitialized memory is uninitialized. Always.

Comment: There is no safe way.

Answer (score 5):

You must *always* be worried about picking up "junk data" and initialize the allocated memory to something meaningful in your program.

Answer (score 3):

There is no promise that memory allocated via malloc will be initialized to a given value.

You should make sure your constructors initialize variables, and that you memset allocated memory to a sane value.

Answer (score 3):

The `malloc()` function basically gets memory from two different places:

1. It requests memory directly from the operating system (the kernel).  On Unix systems such as Linux and OS X, this is done with the `mmap()` or `sbrk()` system calls.  Memory from the kernel is always zero-initialized to begin with.
2. It reuses memory that was freed earlier with `free()`.  This is always assumed to be full of junk.

Just use `calloc()`.  The `calloc()` function knows which pool the memory came from.  If it came from the OS, then it's already zero-initialized and you get zeroed memory for free.  If the memory is from `free()`, then `calloc()` will zero it for you.  See [why malloc+memset is slower than calloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-slower-than-calloc/2688522#2688522) for more details.

**Summary for the lazy:** The `calloc()` function already performs the optimization you are thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a safe way to avoid this without having to use calloc() or memset() every single time?

There is, at least in Windows. Call [`VirtualAlloc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) directly:

> **VirtualAlloc function (Windows)**
>   Reserves or commits a region of pages in the virtual address space of the calling process. Memory allocated by this function is automatically initialized to zero, unless MEM_RESET is specified.