# How to initialise array dynamically with a default value?

Tags: c

I was initializing array (unsigned short int) of size 100000000 in C 4.3.2 , and other two int array of size 1000000. But while submiting on Online judge, it was giving [SIGSEGV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV) error .

Therefor i decided to initialize my array dynamically with a default value 0, as adding value by loop takes much time.

My question is how to initialise array dynamically with a default value ?

Comment: 100000000 really ?

Comment: at that size, it probably makes sense to request memory from the OS directly via `mmap()` for UNIX-like systems or `VirtualAlloc()` on Windows; conveniently, these functions already zero the memory for you...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) function to initialize memory with `0`,

> The `calloc()` function allocates memory for an array of `nmemb` elements
>          of size bytes each and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.
>          **The memory is set to `zero`.**  If `nmemb` or size is `0`, then `calloc()`
>          returns either `NULL`, or a unique pointer value that can later be
>          successfully passed to `free()`.

```
 calloc(number of elements, sizeof(type));
```

or you can also use `memset()` explicitly to initialize  memory allocated by `malloc()` call.

**Note:** `calloc()` isn't magic either - it will **also** use a loop somewhere to replace the garbage with all zeroes.

**See also:** [Why `malloc()` + `memset()` is slower than `calloc()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-is-slower-than-calloc)

Comment: +1 Probably it would be worth mentioning that `calloc()` isn't magic either - it will **also** use a loop somewhere to replace the garbage with all zeroes.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan You are getting better and better

Comment: @Coffee_lover I am unemployed these days so I am getting time :P :D Thanks!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Now **that** is a reason! :D

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; Especially improving `pointers` tagged posts :)

Comment: please provide citation always, otherwise people like me will be confused. I read a little about calloc and it does do magic for larger memory allocation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-is-slower-than-calloc . ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; Yes. Your way to deal with pointer is easy to understand (and also different from others on SO). Keep it up.

Comment: @haccks, furthermore Grijesh is Mr.ASCII-Man :P, I love his answers!!

Comment: @DavidRF ha ha...yes I like arcii arts, I have given a link of asciiflow in my profile....Thanks very much to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't eliminate the initialization time, no matter what you do. The best you can do is to attempt to *optimize* it. 2 techniques come to mind:

- Efficiently use your HW. Use native size memory accesses to initialize the buffer. E.g., over 32-bit architecture loop and write in 4-byte chunks.
- Unroll the loop to eliminate control overhead.

Unrolling will probably be applied anyway by optimizing compiler.

You can also try to move the initialization overhead to a non-critical section. E.g., you can use static variables that will be zero-initialized upon program start. Or, in contrast, you can delay the initialization till first use (lazy initialization).