# Default value for elements of an array of variable size

Tags: c

Is there any way to assign all elements of an array the value `0` in one go.The array accepts its size from the user. Hence

```
int array[x] = {0};
```

Won't work!

Comment: [`calloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/calloc.html)?

Comment: @Jon that does a heap allocation. The most direct translation is `alloca`, which is nonstandard but available on most platforms

Comment: @Nirk: Stack allocation for something whose size is dictated by the user? I wouldn't.

Comment: [How to initialise array dynamically with a default value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898703/how-to-initialise-array-dynamically-with-a-default-value/17898722#17898722)

Comment: if you have circumstances, use vector instead of normal array.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh If it wasn't C...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to dynamically allocate the memory for this array:

```
int *array;
int x;

scanf("%d\n", &x);

array = malloc(sizeof(int) * x);
```

then set value for all of them

```
memset(array, 0, x);
```

or use calloc:

```
array = calloc(x, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Like there wasn't calloc.

Comment: But remember to `free()` it after use.

Comment: @glglgl yep, memory leaks are not ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *array;
int i;
printf ("Amount of numbers to be entered: ");
scanf ("%d",&i);

array = (int*) calloc (i,sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use memset

void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );

```
int *array = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * x);

memset(array,0,sizeof(int) * x);
```

OR Use:

void* calloc (size_t num, size_t size);

```
int *array = (int *) calloc(x, sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

My best bet is to use `memset` from `string.h` library.

```
memset(array,0,x*sizeof(int));
```

This is not technically initialization, because there is no assignment, it only sets all bytes in given memory to '0' but that's exactly what you want to do here.
Also, consider using `malloc` for creating your array, because the way you do it now, your array will be created on the stack(which has finite capacity) and will be freed when function that creates it returns(just like regular automatic variable). That means your array is inaccessible from outside of its local scope.