# Malloc Memset is this usage right ?

Tags: c++, malloc, memset, static-cast

Whats wrong with this usage

```
void* buffer ; 
buffer = (void *)malloc(4096) ; 
memset( buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer) ); 

int *data = static_cast<int*>(buffer) ;
for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
{
    cout<< data[i] << "\n" ;
}
```

I get garbage values in the output. Am I using memset wrong ?

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in C++ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(buffer)` is returning you the size of `void*` (the size of a void pointer). Which has nothing to do with the size of memory block.

The size of `void*` is commonly 4 or 8 bytes, but this depends on the platform. So `memset()` is only clearing a few bytes in the beginning of the array. To clear all of it, you have to pass in the exact size in bytes of the array. In this case 4096.

`sizeof` would actually return the size in bytes of the memory block if it where a block statically allocated, such as `char buffer[4096]`. Remember that `sizeof` is resolved at compile-time. So the static array is the only case when the compiler can resolve the length of an array. With a dynamically allocated array, the compiler has no way of knowing the size. Regardless of the array data type, `char*`, `int*`, `std::string*`, calling `sizeof` on the pointer will always return the size of the pointer variable, not the size of the memory it points to.

Comment: Oh wow my fundamentals are flawed. I thought sizeof would return the full size, since it has already been malloced

Comment: @user1967230, just expanded the answer to clarify a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

As glampert already answered, the problem was that sizeof(buffer) doesn't express the amount of memory allocated, but the size of the pointer. So you could instead write

```
const int size = 4096;
void* buffer = malloc(size); 
memset( buffer, 0, size ); 

int *data = static_cast<int*>(buffer) ;
for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
{
    cout<< data[i] << "\n" ;
}
free( buffer );
```

Another way, [perhaps a bit faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2688522/35440), would be

```
const int size = 4096;
void* buffer = calloc(size);  // return a newly allocated memory block which is zeroed

int *data = static_cast<int*>(buffer) ;
for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
{
    cout<< data[i] << "\n" ;
}
free( buffer );
```

But since you are using C++, it might be more appropriate to do it like this:

```
int *data = new int[ 10 ];
for ( int i=0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    data[ i ] = 0;
}
for( int i=0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    cout<< data[i] << "\n" ;
}
delete [] data;
```

Or even better:

```
int *data = new int[ 10 ](); // allocated array will be zeroed out
for( int i=0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    cout<< data[i] << "\n" ;
}
delete [] data;
```