# F#: Why is Array.createZero so fast?

Tags: arrays, f#, initialization, array-initialization

I have this code:

```
let timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
timer.Start()
Array.zeroCreate<int> 100000000

timer.Stop()
printfn "%ims" timer.ElapsedMilliseconds

timer.Reset()
timer.Start()
Array.create 100000000 0

timer.Stop()
printfn "%ims" timer.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

I tested it and had these results:

```
0ms
200ms
```

How does `Array.zeroCreate` create array so fast and it's guaranteed that all it's elements have default value? In other languages I know there are no such possibilities (as far as I know). In other languages I know only about fast initialization of array which elements are not guaranteed to have default value, because they can be initialized in memory where some garbage lies.

Thanks!

Comment: Hm, 100MB allocated in 0ms? That is surprisingly fast. Maybe a benchmark error. Are you sure the allocation actually took place?

Comment: @usr, yes. I binded arrays to variables and results were the same with Array.zeroCreate and a little different with Array.create. Allocation happened. Both arrays were identical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So we can just go and look up the source:

```
    [<CompiledName("ZeroCreate")>]
    let zeroCreate count =
        if count < 0 then invalidArg "count" (SR.GetString(SR.inputMustBeNonNegative))
        Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.Array.zeroCreateUnchecked count
```

and

```
    [<CompiledName("Create")>]
    let create (count:int) (x:'T) =
        if count < 0 then invalidArg "count" (SR.GetString(SR.inputMustBeNonNegative))
        let array = (Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.Array.zeroCreateUnchecked count : 'T[])
        for i = 0 to Operators.Checked.(-) count 1 do // use checked arithmetic here to satisfy FxCop
            array.[i] <- x
        array
```

so from this we can see that `Create` does some more work - so it is slower.

We can go deeper and find the underlying function:

```
// The input parameter should be checked by callers if necessary
let inline zeroCreateUnchecked (count:int) =
    (# "newarr !0" type ('T) count : 'T array #)
```

this basically just executes the CIL `newarr` instruction.

This instruction could quite conceiveably be executed by calling `calloc` with an appropriate size, which would be incredibly fast.

Comment: It's worth mentioning why `calloc` (and its equivalents) can be so fast:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-is-slower-than-calloc