# Why is this piece of code not faster?

Tags: performance, f#

I've made a "copy" of a piece of java code that runs in approx. 400 ms (https://gist.github.com/threecee/cb1c55ad1ce9ac4b1903). My version in F# that uses `Parallel.ForEach` and I have also tried with `PSeq` but none of the versions is faster than 7 seconds.

It's not that I must have my piece of code faster than the one I copied but I would really like to know what could have been done to improve the performance in a sample calculations like this in F#.

```
open System.Threading.Tasks
#time 
let calculateProducts n =
    let bits = [| for i in 1 .. ((n+1)*(n+1)) -> 0 |]
    let inner i =
        [|i..n|] |> Array.map (fun j -> bits.[j*i] <- 1) |> ignore
    Parallel.ForEach([|1 .. n|], (fun i -> inner i)) |> ignore
    bits |> Array.sum
printfn "%i" (calculateProducts 8000)
```

What the code does is calculating all the unique products `x*y where x: 1->8000 and y: 1-8000`.

**UPDATE:**
The updated code after using `Array.init` as jpe suggested in an answer look likes this:

```
open System.Threading.Tasks
#time 
let calculateProducts n =
    let bits = Array.init ((n+1)*(n+1)) (fun _ -> 0)        
    let inner i =
        let arr = Array.init (n-i+1) (fun x -> x+i)
        Parallel.ForEach(arr, (fun j -> bits.[j*i] <- 1)) |> ignore
    let arr = Array.init n (fun x -> (x+1))
    Parallel.ForEach(arr, (fun i -> inner i)) |> ignore
    bits |> Array.sum
printfn "%i" (calculateProducts 8000)
```

Comment: Just using `Parallel.ForEach` does not automatically imply better performance... There´s a performance penalty due to thread-/task-initialization, which probably takes longer than the actual operation within the loop.

Comment: @Matze, so what do you suggest to improve this? I do think it should be possible to come to close to the performance of the linked to java code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the built in array initialization code as your current array initialization takes ages in the example. Thus replace the line

```
let bits = [| for i in 1 .. ((n+1)*(n+1)) -> 0 |]
```

with line

```
let bits = Array.init ((n+1)*(n+1)) (fun _ -> 0)
```

and you should get performance comparable to the Java code.

Update: As John Palmer suggested, `Array.zeroCreate` will make initializing an array to zeros even faster. Thus if you just need to initialize the array to zeros and not compute any initial values, then use

```
let bits = Array.zeroCreate ((n+1)*(n+1))
```

Update: The reason why it is so fast has previously been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340843/f-why-is-array-createzero-so-fast). Short summary: it uses the appropriate IL bytecode command `newarr` for initialization that in turn has been optimized in the runtime of .Net to be very fast.  `Array.init` is faster than straight forward "manual" initialization because it calls `zeroCreateUnchecked` to initialize the array and then runs the initialization function over the already initialized array.

If you wonder where the code is then here are the links: [implementation of Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Array](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/array.fs) that in turn calls [internal implementation in Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.Array](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/local.fs).

Comment: Thank you sir. Didn't know that Array.init is so much faster. Do you know it is faster?

Comment: You can go even faster with `Array.zeroCreate`

Answer (score 0):

I think the theoretical answer for WHY Java is so much faster could be here:
http://palladin.github.io/StreamsPresentation/#/10

Using that library in F# should possibly (or at least its "promised" to) be faster.

Its source is available at: 
https://github.com/nessos/Streams

Or at nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Streams/

Hopefully then you are comparing Java apples and F# apples (ok not apples, but streams ;-)

It wont change your code to much either I think...