# Correct way to free/allocate the context in the OpenSSL

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, aes

I'am using the Open SSL in my program, to encrypt and decrypt the data using aes ciphers. At the moment there is a little memory leak, so i'm looking for a way to fix that. In my encrypt decrypt routines, i have the contexts free like so

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
```

And created by:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new
```

This was on the OpenSSL wiki page in the [examples](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption)

But! On the MAN page, there is a suggestion for using `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup` and `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init` functions. So basically what should be correct to use, is the `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new`/`EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free` is somehow deprecated? And is there any big difference between `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new`/`EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free` and `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init` / `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup` ?

```
if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) return -1;


  if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
  {
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    return -1;
  }

  if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
  {
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    return -1;
  }
  ciphertext_len = len;


  if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len)) { EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx); return -1; }
  ciphertext_len += len;


  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
```

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Allright, i think it's cleared now. If you do `EVP` style encryption/decryption, make sure you create the context like so:

```
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
```

And free it like so:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
```

Don't use `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new`/`EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free` to create/free the context, they are deprecated!

Comment: It's the opposite I think. In fact openssl-1.1.0 makes EVP_CIPHER_CTX an opaque type, so the first form above is a compile error

Comment: This answer has it exactly backwards as stated in the other answers.  Please update or unaccept it.

Answer (score 35):

First of all if you want a precise answer, you should always specify which version of [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org) you are using. FYI 1.0.2 is current [Long Term Support](https://www.openssl.org/policies/releasestrat.html) version, while 1.1.0 is the newest (in Sept 2016).

If you read the 1.1.0 man pages you will notice:

> EVP_CIPHER_CTX was made opaque in OpenSSL 1.1.0. As a result,
>   EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset() appeared and EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup()
>   disappeared. EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init() remains as an alias for
>   EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset().

Short answer is: you should use `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new` to initialize and `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free` do free the memory, regardless of the version, here's why.

**Allocating:**

1.0.2 man pages say:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
```

and 1.1.0 man pages say:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
```

If you look at the [code](https://www.openssl.org/source/) of EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init in 1.0.2

```
void EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx)
{
   memset(ctx, 0, sizeof(EVP_CIPHER_CTX));
   /* ctx->cipher=NULL; */
}
```

while EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new is:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new(void)
{
   EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = OPENSSL_malloc(sizeof *ctx);
   if (ctx)
      EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(ctx);
   return ctx;
}
```

so you you are still better off initializing the context, like in 1.1.0 example:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
```

for 1.1.0 the same applies.

**For freeing the memory:**

1.0.2 man pages:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
```

1.1.0 man pages:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
```

But if you check the [code](https://www.openssl.org/source/) you can see that for 1.0.2:

```
void EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx)
{
   if (ctx) {
       EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
      OPENSSL_free(ctx);
   }
}
```

So you should use `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free` for deallocating.
If you just want to reset the context for another operation then `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup`(1.0.2) and `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset`(1.1.0) are your friends.

If you are curious about `malloc` `memset` and `calloc`, here's a [good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-is-slower-than-calloc)

Comment: with EVP_CIPHER_CTX/EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free, but valgrind  show that definitely lost memory.

Answer (score 6):

You should not use `EVP_EncryptInit` anymore. That function did automatically create a specific context, but it didn't support the crypto engines that were later added. `EVP_EncryptInit_ex` however explicitly states that:

> `ctx` must be initialized before calling this function.

so you are required to use `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new` here I suppose.

`EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free` is another matter, it seems to have been deprecated, I don't see any mention of it on the manual pages of OpenSSL. It is good practice (and *required* for NIST certified functionality) to delete key material and other state of a cipher after use. Otherwise an attacker may scan the memory or use an overflow at a later stage.

The name of `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free` only indicates that the CTX memory should be released. But freeing of memory does not imply that it is scrubbed of sensitive information first; it's just returned to the system, which is under no obligation to overwrite it either. `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup` on the other hand does explicitly scrub such information before freeing the memory (or it does at least make a decent attempt to do so, I presume). So you need to call this function after you've supplied your key material.

Comment: I don't think your memory issue is within the context, looking at your code. You may want to try some other things such as static code analyzers.