# Initializing to zero after malloc or calling calloc

Tags: c, malloc, calloc

I have a small confusion in using calloc over malloc. I remember somewhere I have read that calloc is slower than malloc because calloc performs initialization to zero after performing memory allocation.

In the project I am working, I see that after malloc they are assigning zero to all the values as shown below,

```
str* strptr = (str*)malloc(sizeof(str));
memset(strptr,0,sizeof(str));
```

Here str is a structure.

This is similar to

```
str* strptr =(str*)calloc(1,sizeof(str));
```

I want to know whether using malloc over calloc has any advantages and which method is preferred.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-is-slower-than-calloc

Comment: I would say, generally, malloc would be better because you will not be referring to the contents of allocated memory before you put something there. A possible exception might be if you're using the zeroes as a check whether you have indeed filled that location yet.

Comment: That's a `memcpy` (mem **copy**) not a `memset`, so they are copying some variable `o` to the struct, which may or may not set all the values to zero.

Comment: @user3386109 : sorry my mistake its memset with zero

Comment: @TheBigH +1 when you don't need zeroing memory (which is mostly the case), then preferring `malloc` makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know whether using malloc over calloc has any advantages

The differences between them are just

- [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) also takes object count as opposed to [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) which only takes byte count
- `calloc` zeros memory; `malloc` leaves the memory uninitialized

So no exceptional advantages except for the zeroing part.

> which method is preferred.

Why not use `malloc` the way its used in the code base you're looking at? To avoid duplication of work and code; when an API already does that why reinvent the wheel? You could have seen code bases with a utility function that does just that: allocate and [zero memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366920%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This shows that the snippet will be used many times and hence they wrap it in a macro/function to call it from different places. However, why do it when `calloc` already does that?

[The best code is no code at all.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-best-code-is-no-code-at-all/) Lesser code is better, and thus you should prefer `calloc` over `malloc` here. May be the optimizer would do the same thing underneath, but why take the chance? Apparently, the optimizer may not be that smart, which is the reason for this question: [Why malloc+memset is slower than calloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2688466/183120)

Also the `calloc` route requires lesser key strokes.