# C - How to use own value (instead of 0) with calloc

Tags: c, initialization, calloc

In C when we use the calloc method; all the reserved memory will be initialized to `0`.

Is there any way to initialize it with another value **without** iterating over all the values?
For example:

```
int* example = calloc(100,sizeof(int));
```

This will create an array of 100 zero's, but I want this to be (for example) 100 ones.

Comment: malloc it and call memset on the malloc'ed chunk

Comment: Suppose I got an initialized "object" of a struct ( and example will be of type struct*  of course). Will this "object" be copied for each of the 100 memory locations?

Comment: Another example of the phrase "As we know" claiming something wrong. The memory is initialised with [**all bits zero**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.2p2) which is not necessarily the same as a `0`/`0.0` or a null pointer. `calloc`, like `memset` has no idea about the structure of the block. And C does not have _methods_. `calloc` is a _function_!

Comment: You mean if 00000000 on a machine means for example the character 'a'.  Then calloc will initialize everything to 'a'?

Comment: Okay. I understand it. Thank you all for the information. :)

Comment: 1) please use `@` to address a commenter, otherwise ysour comment might get unnoticed. 2) see my answer.

Comment: If we had access to the underlying memory system, for large sizes, code could initialize one page of memory to the desired value and map all other pages of the memory assignment to the _same_ page.  So a less than O(n) solution for the moment.  Later as code changes the values, the memory mapped pages would need to diverge, taking time.  But this time is spread out over code run-time.  This trick is used  by many systems for the value of 0 (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-is-slower-than-calloc?rq=1)).

Answer (score 5):

`calloc` as much as `memset` has no idea about the structure of the data stored in the allocated block. It is actually of little use to use `memset` with anything different from `0` on something other than an array of `char` type. Note that `calloc` is **functionally** `malloc` plus `memset(..., 0)`, but might be significantly faster in some implementations.

According to the standard, `calloc` does not store `0`, but [sets all bits zero](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.2p2). This does not necessarily result in a float `0.0` or a null pointer constant, as they might have other binary representations. For integer types, however, `0` has all bits zero, so **this** works.

But only for the `0`, because on most (if not all) modern platforms integer uses at least 2 bytes, so if you set byte-wise, you will touch different bytes of the same integer. Just try `memset(..., 3)`, for 32 bit `int` you will read `0x03030303`, for 64 bit `0x0303030303030303`.

To set structured values of an allocated array, there is no way around using a loop:

```
// here we use int, but that can also be float or a struct
int *a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * 5);
if ( a != NULL ) {
    for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
        a[i] = 1;    // for a struct use a compound literal or set per field

    ...
    free(a);
}
```

You should not worry about performance in the first place. The pattern above is very likely recognised by your compiler and replaced by highly optimised code which will be as fast (if not faster) as `memset` (but not `calloc`).

Comment: "that `calloc` is just `malloc` plus `memset(..., 0)`" is not so.  Example [Why malloc+memset is slower than calloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-is-slower-than-calloc?rq=1)

Comment: @chux: I edited. However this is beyond the abstract machine.

Comment: Might want to catch a few typos too.

Answer (score 4):

```
int* example;
example=malloc(100*sizeof(int));    // allocate memory to store 100 int
if(example){
    memset(example,1,100*sizeof(int));  // initialize it with value 1
}
```

### EDIT

Despite someone upvoted for the above code but (*I made a mistake and now correcting it*) -
**Above example is wrong** .As from manpage  -

> The memset() function fills the first n bytes of the memory area pointed to by s with the constant byte c.

So , the above piece of code will not work as expected .

```
// allocate memory as you do 
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
      example[i]=1;
}
 free(example);
```

This will do the work .

Answer (score 1):

Let the compiler figure it out how to do it quickly by copying large chucks with `memcpy()` - certainly an optimized function call.

```
int *alloc_int_preset(int value, size_t count) {
  int *begin = malloc(sizeof *begin * count);
  if (begin && count) {
    count--;
    size_t n = 1;
    *begin = value;
    int *p = &begin[1];  // place to copy to
    while (count > 0) {
      size_t i = min(count, n);
      // perform memcpy() in ever doubling in size blocks
      memcpy(p, begin, sizeof *p * i);
      p += i;  // advance i `int`s
      n += i;  // advance i
      count -= i;
    }
  }
  return begin;
}
```

1st time through the loop, `memcpy(&begin[1], begin, sizeof *p * 1)`
2nd time through the loop, `memcpy(&begin[2], begin, sizeof *p * 2)`
3rd time through the loop, `memcpy(&begin[4], begin, sizeof *p * 4)`
4th time through the loop, `memcpy(&begin[8], begin, sizeof *p * 8)`

Comment: I smell potential for UB. Also I suspect this is really faster than the `for` loop pattern.

Comment: @Olaf  Apply thy nose and try to find it.  No UB.

Comment: It is not where you might think. You do not check the result of `malloc` (I just  wrote "potential", not it is there)

Comment: @Olaf  I think `assert(begin)` will do that .

Comment: @ameyCU: Do you ship debugging versions of your code to end-customers?

Comment: @Olaf I did not use `assert(begin)` right after the `malloc()` as that may falsely fire when `count == 0` and `malloc()` legitimately returns `NULL`.  So the test is after `if (count) {`.

Comment: @Olaf Sorry , I don't quite understand that , was it a sarcasm or anything else ? If genuine i would say No .  Please bear with me :)

Comment: @Olaf Yet easy enough to improve per your concern.

Comment: @chux: You should test `count` actually before `malloc`. The behaviour is implementation defined for `0` size.

Comment: @ameyCU: It was. `assert` is a NOP unless `NDEBUG` is `#define`d. (but that would not be the first debug version shipped)

Comment: @Oalf When `count == 0` and then maybe `malloc(0)`, OP has not identified the desired behavior in this corner case.  IAC, the above answer does address the larger issue of offering a performance candidate that relies heavily on `memcpy()`.  The "best" answer may be a platform specific decision point between using a [basic loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33176746/2410359) and then this answer for large `count`.

Comment: @Olaf Ohh , that's what you meant .

Comment: @chux: I very well doubt reading/writing from/to memory is faster than storing a register. It might be, for a `struct`, however. It is a good way to cache-trashing once the array becomes larger. To me it looks like preliminary optimisation at best. It certainly is harder to maintain.

Comment: @Olaf With so many platforms that C runs on, board conclusions on performance readily fail.  Benchmarking/Profiling helps.  Of course the `for()` loop functions as needed and is easy to code/maintain - I am confident OP knows about that. OP is certainly seeking potential faster solutions and is willing to incur more maintenance, so maintenance is of secondary importance.