# When I 0-Initialize a vector Does It Have the Same Effect as calloc?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, calloc, zero-initialization

So `calloc` calls on the OS to retrieve zeroed pages on the heap: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2688522/2642059

What about C++11's `vector` constructor that only takes a `size_t` and 0-initializes the values? Ask the OS for a zeroed page in the general case, or does it need to initialize it's self because the `vector`'s elements may be a class with a default initializer, which defaults members to a non-zero value?

Comment: The default constructor for each element is called, thus is definitely something more than calling just `calloc`.

Comment: The `calloc` *can* ask the operating system for already zeroed pages, but if the operating system doesn't supports it it works like normal `malloc` followed by a `memset`.

Comment: @101010: That is true for the non-specialized `std::vector<T>`, but an implementor can specialize `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: It's not specified by the standard, but when it comes to performance optimization, the implementation are usually free to do as they please, as long as it doesn't change the behaviour of the function. I guess an implementation could check for `std::is_trivially_default_constructible<T>` and use `calloc` if it judges it performs better on their platform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector<T>` is part of the implementation, which means we can only see the results, not necessarily the magic behind the scenes. Furthermore, the implementation itself may (partially) specialize `std::vector<T>` as long as the observable results stay the same.

However, that doesn't mean `std::vector<int>` can just ask the OS for zeroed memory. It still has to go through `std::allocator` and `::operator new`, even if you replaced the latter.

Of course, by the laws of compiler magic, if the compiler knows that you didn't, it may still ask the OS directly. But the chief problem with that logic is separate compilation. When compiling A.cpp containing `std::vector<int>`, the compiler won't know that B.cpp contains `::operator new`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that last comment? What do you mean by B.cpp containing `::operator new`?

Comment: Well, that problem can (in theory) be avoided with whole program optimization, and detecting a default `::new`.  I have seen a number of optimizations that are only possible if we presume default `::new`, such as this one and eliminating allocations completely.  Also, `vector` need not be actual c++ code (but it (almost?) always is)

Comment: @JonathanMee: `::operator new` is special in that you can define it, but if you don't define it anywhere you will get a default implementation. Exactly how this works is a detail of the compiler/linker.

Comment: So I just realized that I could have looked at the complexity section, which is called out as linear, so you're right, apart from compiler magic this will be done iteratively: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector#Complexity

Comment: @JonathanMee Complexity guarantees are upper bounds, not tight bounds.