# allocate but don't construct a large array of C++ objects

Tags: performance, optimization, constructor, c++14, large-data

In some circumstances, my C++14 program needs a "block" of about 100 millions `complex<float>`, which requires close to 1 GB of RAM. We can safely assume that the required memory will be available.

However allocating a new `std::vector` is really slow, because the complex constructor is called 100 millions time. On my machine, the code requires around a full second to initialise the array.

By comparison, calling `calloc()`, which initialises the allocated memory to zero, with mostly the same effect, will run in a very small number of milliseconds.

It turns out we don't even need this initialisation, because the complex in the large array will be populated shortly later from an external source. I am looking therefore at deferring the construction of the objects in that "block" to a later time, and then construct them directly from the external data source.

So my question is, is there a safe idiomatic and efficient C++ way to do that, perhaps using C++ move semantics along the way? If not, and we decide to simply `malloc` the memory block, can we then simply `reinterpret_cast` the memory block to a plain old C array of `complex<float>`?

Thank you for helping

Jean-Denis Muys

Comment: Use `std::vector<>`, but use the `reserve()` member function, not `resize()` or the sized constructor.

Comment: Is it really so slow even when you compile it with optimizations? I can't believe it.

Comment: Why do you want to use vector in this case? You can't attach/detach memory to vector, but you can use all std algorithms using pointers instead of iterators.

Comment: I don't *want* to use `vector`. I *tried* `vector` as well as raw `malloc`, and got a huge performance gap that actually matters in my case. I am basically looking for the sweet point between performance, clarity, safety, and similar quality criteria.

Comment: As a side note, `calloc` can often [cheat and not really allocate memory, or wait before really handing out the memory to you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2688522/3460805), the cost come later. Don't rely on its apparently good performance at calling point.

Comment: true. And `malloc()` too, BTW, returning a pointer (not failing), but not really allocating the memory. The memory allocation is then handled by the kernel in a page fault when attempting using the memory block, and potentially only failing *then*.

Comment: @Al Kepp yes the slow down is over a thousand fold. The reason is probably the implementation of `calloc` as described at the page linked to by @Chnossos

Comment: I'd hope that a compiler would be able to optimize `vector<std::complex>(N)` to a `calloc` call... if that doesn't seem to be happening then it would be a good thing to submit as a bug or suggested improvement

Comment: My compiler (clang) doesn't do that optimisation. Does your?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest to stick to c++ and avoid manually managing the memory yourself.

The standard library should be enough. E.g.

```
std::vector< complex > my_vector;

// Reserve the necessary space without constructing anything
my_vector.reserve( 100'000'000); 

// construct the elements when needed
populate( my_vector );
```

Comment: I agree with your "strong suggestion". I will try to use `vector::reserve()`

Answer (score 3):

If you define the default constructor for the `complex<float>` class as empty, which leaves the member variables uninitialized, then there shouldn't be any real difference between the two operations given that compiler optimizations are turned on.

Assuming the below definition for the `complex` class.

```
template <typename T>
struct complex
{
  complex() {}; // Empty constructor does nothing
  T a, b;
};
```

The generated assembly for using `vector` initialization with x86-64 gcc 6.2 and -O2 enabled is:

```
std::vector<complex<float>> v(100);

    mov     edi, 800
    call    operator new(unsigned long)
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    operator delete(void*)
```

And the generated assembly for manually calling `malloc` and `free` is:

```
auto v = malloc(100 * sizeof(complex<float>));
free(v);

    mov     edi, 800
    call    malloc
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], rax
    mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]
    call    free
```

As you can see, the `vector` implementation no longer calls the constructor of `complex<float>` for each element. The usage of `vector` is more correct and readable, and also takes advantage of RAII which helps to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: this is a very good point. Of course, this solution requires defining a custom complex class, rather than using `std::complex`

Comment: in my environment (clang on the mac), the complex default constructor is defined this: `complex(const value_type& __re = value_type(), const value_type& __im = value_type())
        : __re_(__re), __im_(__im) {}`

Comment: I see, so it looks like `std::complex` always initializes its real and imaginary values, which would always give you a slowdown if you initialize them all at once in an `std::vector`.

Comment: Yes, and currently, no level of Clang optimisation will optimise this out

Comment: Actually, interestingly testing with x86-64 clang 3.9.0 yields optimized assembly code for `std::vector<std::complex<float> > v(100);`. However it seems that x86-64 gcc 6.2 will instead call the constructor for each element for std::complex. [Try it online here](https://godbolt.org/g/xEPWTk)

Comment: my compiler (Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42)) behaves as GCC: it calls the complex constructor in a loop. So does Clang 3.8.1 or earlier at the page you link. Unfortunately, Apple has stopped reporting on which LLVM version its compiler is based. This experiment seems to demonstrate it's based on a version earlier than 3.9 though. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

So your question is if you can use `malloc()`. I used the same approach many years ago with my old C++ compiler and it worked. But at the end I had to call `free()` instead of `delete[]`. I think this is implementation-specific, so you should try it on your compiler.