# Why memset called after calloc?

Tags: c, malloc, calloc, memset

I've researched code of some library and noticed that calls to `calloc` there are followed by `memset` for block allocated by `calloc`.
I've found this question with quite comprehensive answer on differences between `calloc` and `malloc` + `memset` and calling `memset` for just before allocated storage:

[Why malloc+memset is slower than calloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-is-slower-than-calloc)

What i still can't understand is why one would want to do so.
What are benefits of this operations?

The code example from mentioned above library:

```
light_pcapng_file_info *light_create_default_file_info()
{
    light_pcapng_file_info *default_file_info = calloc(1, sizeof(light_pcapng_file_info));
    memset(default_file_info, 0, sizeof(light_pcapng_file_info));
    default_file_info->major_version = 1;
    return default_file_info;
}
```

The code of allocated structure(each array contains 32 elements):

```
typedef struct _light_pcapng_file_info {
    uint16_t major_version;
    uint16_t minor_version;
    char *file_comment;
    size_t file_comment_size;
    char *hardware_desc;
    size_t hardware_desc_size;
    char *os_desc;
    size_t os_desc_size;
    char *user_app_desc;
    size_t user_app_desc_size;
    size_t interface_block_count;
    uint16_t link_types[MAX_SUPPORTED_INTERFACE_BLOCKS];
    double timestamp_resolution[MAX_SUPPORTED_INTERFACE_BLOCKS];

} light_pcapng_file_info;
```

**EDIT:**

In addition to accepted answer i'd like to provide some info my colleague pointed me to. There was a bug in glibc which, sometimes, prevented calloc from zeroing out memory. Here's the link:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1293976

Actual bug report text in case link gets moved:

**glibc: calloc() returns non-zero'ed memory**

Description of problem:

At Facebook we had an app that started hanging and crashing weirdly when going from glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 to glibc-2.12-1.163.el6.x86_64.  Turns out this patch

glibc-rh1066724.patch

Introduced the problem.

You added the following bit to _int_malloc()

```
  /* There are no usable arenas.  Fall back to sysmalloc to get a chunk from
     mmap.  */
  if (__glibc_unlikely (av == NULL))
    {
      void *p = sYSMALLOc (nb, av);
      if (p != NULL)
       alloc_perturb (p, bytes);
      return p;
    }
```

But this isn't ok, alloc_perturb unconditionally memset's the front byte to 0xf, unlike upstream where it checks to see if perturb_byte is set.  This needs to be changed to

```
if (p != NULL && && __builtin_expect(perturb_byte, 0))
   alloc_perturb (p, bytes);
return p;
```

The patch I've attached fixes the problem for me.

This problem is exacerbated by the fact that any sort of lock contention on the arena's results in us falling back on mmap()'ing a new chunk.  This is because we check to see if the uncontended arena we check is corrupt, and if it is we loop through, and if we loop to the beginning we know we didn't find anything.  Except if our initial arena isn't actually corrupt we'll still return NULL, so we fall back on this mmap() thing more often, which really makes things unstable.

Please get this fixed as soon as possible, I'd even go so far as to call it a possible security issue.

Comment: [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) already 0-initializes the memory, so using `memset` to do it again is pointless (unless you're dealing with a buggy `calloc` implementation).

Comment: Perhaps the library author didn't use `calloc` at first, but `malloc`? Perhaps the author of the library doesn't really know what `calloc` is supposed to do? Perhaps there are a myriad of other reasons? The only one who can answer is the original author. All we can do is *guess*.

Comment: The code was written by some rookie. And that's it... nothing to ponder over.

Comment: Reading other code, to learn from it, is important, but it does have this ugly downside: there's a lot of staggeringly badly written code out there, and this is one little example.  There is absolutely no point in calling memset after calloc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `memset()` ensures that the OS actually does the virtual memory mapping.  As noted in the answers on the question you linked, `calloc()` can be optimized so that the actual memory mapping is deferred.

The application might have reasons to **not** defer the actual creation of the virtual memory mapping - such as using the buffer to read from a very high-speed device, although in the case of using `memset()` to zero out the memory, using `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` does seem redundant.

Comment: No, this doesn't explain why. You could merely touch a single memory cell to achieve that - you don't have to zero out the whole allocated memory just to force the allocation. It would be needlessly inefficient.

Comment: @Lundin Should it not be one memory cell *per page* that needs to be touched? In the example in the OP's post it's probably a single page (or even part of a page), but if the memory spans multiple pages and the page-size is unknown then a `memset` call might be simpler.

Comment: @Lundin *you don't have to zero out the whole allocated memory just to force the allocation. it would be needlessly inefficient.*  And you can also skew your offset to get better performance because of cache striding. And if it's a huge bit of memory and you want to get it faster, you can do the touching of each page with many threads.  But `memset()` does it all in one line of code.  (Yeah, I've had to do all that...)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That would mean that this was some system-specific port. But it is true that we don't know how big the struct is.

Comment: At any rate, if the purpose was to force allocation, I would definitely have expected some comment which explained that was the purpose.

Comment: Note that `gcc 8.2.1` happily optimizes out `memset()` to zero after `calloc()`, so this attempt at pre-faulting the addresses will break with a sane compiler *anyway*.

Comment: @Lundin  but "The code was written by some rookie."  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Nobody is perfect, that's all. Yes, `memset` to zero following a `calloc` is extravagant. If you want an explicit `memset` in order to guarantee you are in possession of the memory that you've asked for, then it should follow a `malloc` instead.

New code has about 20 bugs per 1,000 lines and the laws of probability imply that not all of them are weeded out. Plus this is not really a bug, as there's no ill-behaviour to be observed.

Answer (score 1):

I would call it a bug, since it's doing pointless work, `calloc()` is specified to return already-cleared memory so why clear it again? Perhaps a failed refactoring, when someone switched from `malloc()`.

If the code is open source and/or in a repository you have access to, I would check the commit history for those lines and see what has been going on. With a bit of luck, there's a commit message that tells the motivation ...

Comment: It's not completely pointless - calling `memset()` ensures the virtual memory pages are actually created.  Although if that's the reason for the code, `malloc()` then `memset()` would be a better choice.

Comment: As already mentioned in [comments on another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54574920/why-memset-called-after-calloc#comment95947981_54574991), modern compilers optimize malloc+memset(0) into calloc, which may get untouched zeroed pages from the OS.  (This can happen even with a zeroing loop: compilers also know how to optimize a loop into a memset call, e.g. to take advantage of hand-tuned asm for the current CPU, and then the malloc+memset(0) optimization applies.)