# C - calloc() v. malloc()

Tags: c, malloc, calloc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c difference between malloc and calloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538420/c-difference-between-malloc-and-calloc)

Please explain the significance of this statement,

> Another
>   difference between the malloc() and
>   calloc() functions is that the memory
>   allocated by malloc( ) function
>   contains garbage values, while memory
>   allocated by calloc( ) function
>   contains all zeros.

Source (*'C' Programming*, Salim Y. Amdani)

Thanks

Comment: It seems pretty self explanatory. What's the question?

Comment: Is it that you don't understand what garbage values are?

Comment: Why would malloc() not initialize? It seems to me that calloc() should be used over malloc(), assuming that initializing memory is a good practice.

Comment: What if you wanted to use that memory for something other than all zeros?  Then you've wasted the time it took to memset it all to 0.

Comment: there's no reason to zero out memory if you initialize the memory to stuff right after . e.g. copying a string into the malloc'ed memory, initializing a structure with various values, etc.

Comment: What does it mean to initialize memory to 0? I am kind of lost.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Is_it_better_to_use_malloc_or_calloc_to_allocate_memory

`malloc()` is faster, since `calloc()` initializes the allocated memory to contain all zeros.  Since you typically would want to use and initialize the memory yourself, this additional benefit of `calloc()` may not be necessary.

Comment: According to this recent article this is not true.  He shows that calloc is mostly faster and has several other benefits as well.  https://vorpus.org/blog/why-does-calloc-exist/

Comment: I concur, calloc is not only usually faster on a modern system, it's sometimes much faster and it can avoid some embarrassing bugs! For embedded stuff, YMMV.

Answer (score 25):

`calloc` is initializing the memory before you use it, but `malloc` does not.

Refer to [this](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/calloc.html) link:

> The calloc() function shall allocate
>   unused space for an array of nelem
>   elements each of whose size in bytes
>   is elsize. The space shall be
>   initialized to all bits 0.

With `malloc`, if you want to guarantee the same effect you'd have to call something like memset to reset the memory, e.g.

```
char* buffer = (char*)malloc(100);
memset(buffer,0,100);
```

`calloc` saves you that extra step.
The significance of initializing memory is that you are getting a variable to a known state rather than an unknown one. So if you are checking a variable, say an array element, for an expected value, then by having pre-initialized the variable ahead of time, you can be sure that the value you are checking isn't garbage. **In other words, you can distinguish between garbage and legitimate values.**

For example, if you just leave garbage in the variable and you are checking for some value, say 42, then you have no way of knowing if the value was really set to 42 by your program, or if that's just some garbage leftover because you didn't initialize it.

Comment: Thanks. What's the significance of initializing memory? Why does malloc() not initialize?

Comment: Most of the time, as soon as you allocate memory, you're going to fill in its contents yourself (eg by assigning values to all the elements in an array, or all the fields in a struct). In that case, you don't need the memory to be zeroed before you use it, so you use malloc. If you have a specific need for the memory to be zeroed, you can use calloc. This is equivalent to malloc followed by memset, but might be faster, because the allocator can be clever about it.

Comment: The example is incorrect, `sizeof(buffer)` is equal to `sizeof(char *)`; it will not initialize the entire buffer to zero.

Comment: Imagine if you were allocated a block of land. You don't know where the land is, you don't know what is on the land, all you are given is a deed title. This is what `malloc` effectively does - return a pointer to an area of memory. Now `calloc` might be similar to `malloc` except that the council guarantee to bulldoze everything off the land first. Takes a lot more time, and is therefore more expensive, but you know what you're getting. You choose.

Answer (score 9):

`calloc(...)` is basically `malloc` + `memset`(if you want to 0 initialise the memory)

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct fubar));
memset(ptr, 0, sizeof (struct fubar)); //here we could use some different value instead of 0 whereas calloc always 0 initialises.
```

When you use `malloc` to allocate some memory, it's previous contents are not cleared (ie not initialized). You might get random values that were set when machine booted up or you might see some of the memory that belonged to previously running programs but was left uncleared after allocation and program exit.

`calloc` itself is slower than `malloc` because you have to spend some time to clear the contents of allocated memory. So if you just need to allocate some memory and then copy some stuff there, you are free to use `malloc`.

Comment: don't cast malloc

Comment: @cat, thanks fixed ;)

Answer (score 4):

It just means that if you allocate memory, with calloc(), whatever you allocate is 0.  i.e. if you allocated space for an array of integers, they'd all be set to 0, whereas with malloc(), the memory there isn't initialized in any way.

You could use calloc in situations where you are just going to do a memset of 0 to the memory anyway.