# Why is malloc not "using up" the memory on my computer?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, malloc

So I have this program that allocates 256 MB of memory, and after the user presses ENTER it frees the memory and terminates.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char *p, s[2];

    p = malloc(256 * 1024 * 1024);
    if ( p == NULL) 
        exit(1);

    printf("Allocated"); 
    fgets(s, 2, stdin);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

I ran this program multiple times and backgrounded each of them until there is no longer enough memory that can be allocated. However, that never happens. I ran a linux `top` command and even after running this program many times, the free memory never goes down by nearly as much as 256 MB.

However, on the other hand, if I use `calloc` instead of `malloc` then there is a HUGE difference:

`p = calloc(256 * 1024 * 1024, 1);`

Now if I run the program and background it, and repeat, every time I run it, the free memory goes down by 256 MB. Why is this? Why does `malloc` not cause the available free memory to change, but `calloc` does?

Comment: Run the program via strace, and see what it does. (I'd expect _both_ versions to mmap /dev/zero anonymously, BTW)

Comment: It's called "Lazy allocation". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712683/what-is-lazy-allocation

Comment: The short, oversimplified answer is that since you haven't actually used the memory from `malloc`, the computer doesn't need to actually give it to you yet. With `calloc` though, the memory needs to be used (for the zeroing out part), and hence the computer actually needs to give you all of it.

Comment: The `top` and `free` commands' "free memory" figures are meaningless. At best they're telling you about cache efficiency. The actual meaningful number, commit charge, can be found in `/proc/meminfo` as the `Committed_AS:` line.

Comment: @DennisMeng: this is only true for [extremely primitive `calloc` implementations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4319790/2171120) – but Ryan is apparently using one of those. BSD omalloc, for example, does not usually access the memory.

Comment: @mirabilos I *did* say oversimplified...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`malloc()` does *not* use memory.  It allocates it.

After you allocate the memory, use it by assigning some data.

```
size_t Size = 256 * 1024 * 1024;
p = malloc(Size);
if (p != NULL) {
  memset(p, 123, Size);
}
```

Some platforms implement `malloc()` is such a way that the physical consumption of memory does not occur until that byte (or more likely a byte within a group or "page" of bytes) is accessed.

`calloc()` may or may not truly *use* the memory either.  A system could *map* lots of memory to the same physical zeroed memory, at least until the data gets interesting.   See 
[Why malloc+memset is slower than calloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-is-slower-than-calloc?rq=1)

Comment: Is 123 your lucky number?  256 MB of 123 123 123 123… Must be very lucky!

Comment: surely it should be 42

Answer (score 13):

The memory may not be really available, especially that you didn't do anything using `p` in your example except check for if it's `NULL`. From [man malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)

> By default, Linux follows an optimistic memory allocation strategy. This means that when `malloc()` returns non-`NULL` there is no guarantee that the memory really is available. In case it turns out that the system is out of memory, one or more processes will be killed by the OOM killer. For more information, see the description of `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` and `/proc/sys/vm/oom_adj` in `proc(5)`, and the Linux kernel source file Documentation `/vm/overcommit-accounting`.

Answer (score 5):

The `calloc` on your system† actually touches the memory by clearing it, and on many systems memory is not really allocated (and thus “used up”) until it is touched by the process to which it is allocated. So just doing `malloc` does not “use” the memory until you, well, use it.

† See comments

Comment: I think `calloc()` can cheat too on some systems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-is-slower-than-calloc?rq=1

Comment: @chux Interesting, I did not know that, thanks for the link. (Meanwhile the asker did find `calloc` and `malloc` different on their system and their parameters.)

Comment: Agreed.  It is not well know and certainly does not apply in OP's case.  Those sneaky OS gremlins!