# C11 stdatomic and calloc

Tags: c, atomic, c11

I've got a structure that contains an atomic field:

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

struct s {
    ...
    atomic_int a;
};
```

This structure is allocated with `calloc`:

```
struct s *p = calloc(1, sizeof(struct s));
```

Is it portable to expect `p->a` to be initialised to 0?  There are enough barriers in the code so that weakly consistent initialisation is fine, but is the initial value guaranteed to be 0?

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, this discussion has resulted in https://github.com/jech/threadpool/commit/63edf80d4605e33254173f1d2b82fbc7da1b249c.

Comment: It also depends on **when** you do the `calloc()` and when you do read the atomic struct field. After looking briefly at your code it seems that you do the `calloc()` before the other threads (that read the atomic) are created. And since `pthread_create()` is one of the pthread functions that [acts as memory barrier](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12) you actually don't have to atomically set it after the `calloc()`, i.e. the `calloc()` alone is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not portable in general. `calloc` only guarantees a byte-wise `0` value of the underlying object. For types that (may) have a state this is not equivalent to an initialization. You definitively have to use `atomic_init` to put your object into a valid state.

The reason for this are platforms that hold a "lock" in addition to the base object because they don't implement the corresponding assembler instruction. So to be portable you really need to use `ATOMIC_VAR_INIT` or `atomic_init` for all atomic objects that are not statically allocated.

That said, I don't know of any existing platform that would need such cruft for `atomic_int`. If your platform has `ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE` set to `2` and `sizeof(atomic_int)==sizeof(int)`, you can be relatively sure that your strategy works. You could test that in a `_Static_assert`.

Comment: Interesting.  Jens's last paragraph refers to Section 7.17.5 of the spec, with the rationale implicit in Section 7.17.8.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is not portable/safe.

It's very likely that `calloc()` end up doing a simple `memset()` on the memory area. This simple `memset()` would not issue the required memory barriers to ensure that other threads reading the structure would see the `p->a` as `0`.

Comment: How might another thread access this object before calloc returns? Only calloc knows its address.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear -- I realise that the initialisation will not be atomic, I'm worried whether the representation of atomic values guarantees that the initial value will be 0.  I've edited the question so it's hopefully clearer.

Comment: @rici It doesn't matter. `calloc()` can return and the pointer can be passed to an other thread. That doesn't guarantee that the second thread will see the memory as initialized. It could still see some previous garbage.

Answer (score -1):

```
struct s *p = calloc(1, sizeof(struct s));
struct s *q = p;
// some other thread
foo(*q);
```

The initialization to zero is accounted for before `p`  or any of its assginees can access the memory.  It is `0`.

Also see [deferred](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19991623/2410359) zero-ing.