# malloc and heap: extra memory for storing the size and linked list information?

Tags: c++, c, memory, malloc, heap-memory

I have a simple question about the `heap` and `malloc`:

When we allocate some memory space using `malloc` as following:

```
int *p;
p = (int*) malloc (10*sizeof(int));
```

It actually allocates 10 words in the heap. However, my question is:

The actual memory space used is really 10 words?

Or there are other extra space needed for storing the value of memory size?

Or, even, because the heap is structured as *Linked list*, is there other memory space being used for storing the address which points to the next node of the list in the heap?

Comment: Yes, malloc has overhead. That's completely implementation-specific. But in general your program will be more memory-efficient if it uses fewer large allocations rather than many small allocations.

Comment: It's implementation defined. However, in any case there is some overhead to manage the allocated memory. You may start reading at: https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Memory_management

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do malloc() and free() work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work)

Comment: While the question is basically the same, the answers have less exposition over there than here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is completely implementation dependent.

a) It could have a few bytes before each allocated node which contains the size of the node, pointer to the next node, and maybe a previous node pointer and the type of node.

b) The returned item may have nothing else around it except other allocations.  A structure elsewhere keeps track of what is allocated and what is free, perhaps by a bitmap or a miniature parallel list.

c) Another variation provides several arrays of fixed sized chunks.  One array may provide 32-byte blocks; another 128-byte blocks, etc.  A bitmap for each array manages allocations.

d) The most minimal implementation I have seen ignores `free()` completely (that is, `free()` is a no op) and allocates the next piece of the pool at each `malloc()`.

---

By far, the most commonly used modern technique is *a*.   Variant *b* is used in many filesystems like NTFS and FAT.  Option *c* was/is favored in many DEC operating systems, especially for kernel use.  Option *d* is used by a few minimalist embedded environments with a suitable caveat.

In most implementations, the requested allocation is rounded up to some natural multiple (usually of 2, 8, 16, etc.) convenient for the algorithm.  So a series of allocations of 5, 3, 8, 7, 4, 1, and 15 might each be regarded as a 16 byte request.

Comment: it's worth noting that there are many other tricks which might cost extra space, like padding with special bitpatterns to detect out-of-bounds write or information about the allocation (which part of the code did the allocation) for debugging purposes.

Comment: Maybe add something about [optimistic allocation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc).  (BTW: A very good answer! )

Comment: @chux:  The man page mention of optimistic allocation is interesting, but I don't see how it fits.  I think it means `sbrk()` is optimistic and could lead to `malloc()` optimism, right?

Comment: OP says "The actual memory space used is really 10 words?" so is thinking `malloc()` and others truly _use_ memory when all that really may happen was memory was marked for use, but not used yet and the "extra memory" may change when true use occurs. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19991623/2410359).  If that does not help, don't bother messing your fine answer.   Note: Optimistic allocation is a separate idea from `sbrk()`.

Answer (score 2):

Memory allocation is dependent on the compiler libraries and the operating system.

Both languages don't state a maximum amount of memory that can be allocated.  All you are guaranteed is the requested size.

So if there is any additional memory allocated, it would be platform dependent.

Also, there may be less overhead when allocating larger spaces.

Try writing your own memory allocator and see what is needed, especially when desposing the memory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible for an implementation of `malloc` to actually allocate a little more memory than what you requested, store the size of the allocated memory at the start of the allocated memory, then give you a pointer to the immediate next memory address. When you call `free` on that pointer, the allocator will go back a little, read the size of the buffer, and figure out how much it needs to actually release.

But of course, another possible implementation could keep a list, or a dictionary, or do something entirely different under the hood, as long as it gives you the same specified behavior.

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate memory using `malloc`, all you get is a pointer to the first address in that memory and a guarantee that so many bytes have been allocated for your use. The details of *how* that memory is allocated and tracked are platform-dependent, and there is no way for you to access that information from within the program. So while extra memory may be allocated for overhead purposes, you can't use that knowledge in a cross-platform way.

Comment: Of course. I was simplifying the situation because thinking about the case in which `malloc` fails doesn't really apply to the question.