# How to create certain elemental array from a pre-defined array

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management

How can I create an array such that I could access the elements `a[1000000]`, `a[1]` and `a[2]` and not even using the size of 1000000?

If possible please provide the answer in `C++`.

Comment: It's called sparse array, STL doesn't implement it. So either do your own or find a library. Or maybe you don't actually need it because hash map can be used the same way.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do? Are you filling the other elements, or is this just some kind of exercise?

Comment: See I have an array of length say N and I want to count the frequency of each element in it, where N<element. For example, I have 10 elements as 10E6 10E6 10E6 10E6 10E6 10E6 10E6 10E6 10E6 10E6 and I want to count the frequency so I have to use count[arr[i]]++ for each iteration.\

Comment: If you want to build a frequency association, a map (ordered or not) will likely give you *exactly* what you're looking for. If you need the association ordered as well (i.e. after building the map, you want to show the top 10 most-frequent), a partial sort will be needed, but the standard library has routines for that as well.

Comment: @SahilSilare If code is `count[arr[i]]++` then **each** element of the array `count[]` needs an initial value - such as 0.  So prior to any incrementing the _entire array_ is initialized/assign and _accessed_.  Instead of an _array_, code could use `unsigned *count = calloc(1000000, sizeof *count);` and see [Why is malloc not “using up” the memory on my computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19991623/2410359) to "save" memory.  Is using a pointer to memory OK rather than using an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::unordered_map<>`.

```
enum { N = 9 };
int arr[N] = { 0 };
std::unordered_map<int, int> m;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    ++m[arr[i]];
}
```

Comment: What if I had 10E5 distinct elements then will you assign every element like this?

Comment: If you have 100000 elements to assign, assign 100000 elements.

Comment: @SahilSilare Exactly the same syntax and usage you would proffer for a regular array. The point of the `operator[]` is to give key access. This is probably going to give you the best bang for he buck. If you need ordered enumeration a regular `map` will work instead. It is very usage dependent, so look at your problem(s) being solved and choose accordingly.