# How important is it to check for malloc failures?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

Is always protecting mallocs important? By protecting I mean:

```
char *test_malloc = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10000);

if (!test_malloc)
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

I mean, in electronic devices, I don't doubt it's essential.
But in programs I'm running on my own machine that I'm sure my allocation size will be positive and that the size will not be astronomical.
Some people say, "Ah imagine there’s not enough memory in your computer at this moment."

Comment: 'I'm sure my allocation size will be positive' , cos none of us ever have bugs in our code :-)

Comment: `in electronic devices, I don't doubt it's essential. But in programs I'm running on my own machine that` - so your machine is not electronic, did I understand it correctly?

Comment: It really depends. If your program is providing life support for someone, and because of failed allocation will crash, it can cause, well, health issues, it's important. If your program is steering a rocket to a target, it's going to blow up anyway. It's hard to answer "how important". How important is your program? `I'm sure my allocation size will be positive and that the size will not be astronomical` The idea is to learn best practices from the start, so that when you'll get to programming life support systems, you will never forget to do it.

Comment: Note that returning non-`NULL` does not insure code is not out-of-memory: [Why is malloc not "using up" the memory on my computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19991623/2410359).

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I mean in small-scale electronic devices, since they have much less capacity.

Comment: @KamilCuk Okay, in fact i already have this habit, but i think its sometimes useless to do this for a few of bytes aha.

Answer (score 1):

There's always the possibility that the system can run out of memory and not have any more to allocate, so it's always a good idea to do so.

Given that there's almost no way to recover from a failed `malloc`, I prefer to use a wrapper function to do the allocation and checking.  That makes the code more readable.

```
void *safe_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *p = malloc(size);
    if (p == NULL) {
        perror("malloc failed!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Exit immediately, with no chance of saving any state first?  Doesn't seem very safe to me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If you're out of memory, odds are nothing else will work.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Given a failure, there's no way to know if just too much was attempted to be allocated or the failure is due to heap corruption. A well designed program will never allow itself to try for too much memory, so heap corruption must/should be the assumption. A "realtime safe" program with predictable throughput/latency requires that _all_ allocation be done during program initialization. No further allocation is permitted.

Answer (score 1):

The other reason it's a good idea to check for `malloc` failures (and why I always do) is: to catch programming mistakes.

It's true, memory is effectively infinite on many machines today, so `malloc` almost never fails because it ran out of memory.  But it often fails (for me, at least) because I screwed up and overwrote memory in some way, screwing up the heap, and the next call to `malloc` often returns `NULL` to let you know it noticed the corruption.  And that's something I really want to know about, and fix.

Over the years, probably 10% of the time `malloc` has returned `NULL` on me was because it was out of memory, and the other 90% was because of those other problems, my problems, that I really needed to know about.

So, to this day, I still maintain a pretty religious habit of *always* checking `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to check for error conditions? Absolutely!

Now when it comes to `malloc` you might find, that *some* implementations of the C standard library – the glibc for example – will never return `NULL` and instead `abort`, due to the assumption that if allocating memory fails, a program won't be able to recover from that. IMHO that assumption is ill founded. But it places `malloc` in that weird groups of function where, even if you properly implement out-of-memory condition handling that works without requesting any more memory, your program is still being crashed.

That being said: You should definitely check for error conditions, for the sole reason you might run your program in an environment that gives you a chance to properly react to them.

Answer (score 0):

The Standard makes no distinction between a number of kinds of implementations:

1. Those where a program a program could allocate as much memory as it `malloc()` will supply, without affecting system stability, and where a program that could behave usefully without needing the storage from the failed allocation may run normally.
2. Those where system memory exhaustion may cause programs to terminate unexpectedly even without `malloc()` ever indicating a failure, but where attempting to dereference a pointer returned via `malloc()` will either access a valid memory region or force program termination.
3. Those where `malloc()` might return null, and dereferencing a null pointer might have unwanted effects *beyond abnormal program termination*, but where programs might be unexpectedly terminated due to a lack of storage even when `malloc()` reports success.

If there's no way a program would be able to usefully continue operation if `malloc()` fails, it's probably best to allocate memory via wrapper function that calls `malloc()` and forcibly terminates the program if it returns null.