# what will happened if I don't protect malloc?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, heap-memory

```
char *str = malloc(1000); // that is ok
// do somthing ...
free(str);

//but what if i didn't protect malloc from failure 

// i mean doing that
char *str = malloc(1000);
if (!str)
    return (0);
//do something ...
free (str);
```

so how can `malloc` fail on reserving memory in heap
and what is the error that can happened

Comment: If you don't check the returned pointer and use it when it is NULL you have undefined behavior. Odds are high your program will crash.

Comment: @RetiredNinja first thank u for your answer, yah i know that but when does malloc fail and return NULL and not a pointer and how can it return NULL that's what i want know actually.

Comment: It will return `NULL` if it can't provide the amount of memory you requested. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/6K35Y7czo)

Comment: but is it possible to run out of memory @TedLyngmo and how can that happened and thank u for you answer

Comment: @MittousIssmail It is possible to run out of memory _handles_, out of memory, or [lie to you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19991656/2410359) and fail later.