# Double linked list; newbie attempt

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I've just started out learning **C**, and (*seemingly*) so far most stuff is clicking. However, I'm having some trouble tracking down an issue with an attempt at a **double linked list**. I keep getting a `seg-fault` when I attempt to build/run this code. I'm compiling with the Cygwin supplied **gcc** via NetBeans.

I hate to just dump a block of code and say "help", but I don't know what other details are pertinent at this time, so feel free to ask for details if necessary:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node_t{
    struct node_t *prev;
    struct node_t *next;
};

struct list_t{
    struct node_t *head;
    struct node_t *tail;
    int length;
};

struct node_t *new_node(void);
struct list_t *new_list(void);
int append_list_node(struct list_t *list, struct node_t *node);

int main(void) {

    int i = 0, length = 0;
    struct node_t *node;
    struct list_t *list = new_list();

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        length = append_list_node(list, new_node());
        printf("%d", length);
    }

    return 0;

}

struct node_t *new_node(void){
    struct node_t *node = malloc(sizeof(struct node_t));
    return node;
}

struct list_t *new_list(void){
    struct list_t *list = malloc(sizeof(struct list_t));
    list->length = 0;
    return list;
}

int append_list_node(struct list_t *list, struct node_t *new_node){
    if(list->head == NULL){
        list->head          = new_node; // edited
        new_node->prev      = NULL;
    }else{
        list->tail->next    = new_node;
        new_node->prev      = list->tail;
    }
    return (++list->length);
}
```

---

**Thanks** for the super quick responses everyone, all the answers are correct. As I was briefly looking over the code between `F5`-ing, I realized I wasn't setting the `tail`, so I resolved to change the line marked `edited` as follows:

```
list->head = list->tail = new_node;
```

I'll also resolve to use `calloc()` however, I've read that frequent use of it can cause considerable costs to execution time since it's clearing and allocating. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you run it with GDB and say where the segmentation fault occurs?

Comment: list->tail->next = new_node;
list->tail is uninitialized when this line is executed for the first time

Comment: **@Maz**: Apparently at the line I've made mention of in my edit. **@yurib**: Thanks, check my edit, hopefully it's a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use calloc() to allocate memory. The malloc() function does not initialize the memory to zeros (so the pointers will be set to NULL). You are making the assumption that the pointers are NULL by default.

Comment: Thanks **Maz**; In my book *C Programming: A Modern Approach 2nd Ed.* it mentions that `calloc` can be costly for execution time. Is there a benchmark for this? Would a large number of calls in tandem be noticeable?

Comment: I'm not aware of any performance slow down resulting from calloc(). If you'd prefer though, you could just use malloc() and then use the memset() function to zero it out yourself.

Comment: There are some comments to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538420/c-difference-between-malloc-and-calloc/1538427#1538427) to a question about `calloc` that discuss performance. You might be interested in reading them.

Comment: Alrighty; I'm only curious as it would make sense, that the extra step to zero out the memory would add to execution time. Surely unnoticeable in most circumstances, however if calling something with exceedingly deep recursion or high iterations, the performance loss may not be so negligible. Not sure myself, gonna hafta investigate.

Comment: @TomcatExodus: in this case you're setting the memory to 0 anyway (setting length to 0 and pointers to NULL). it's faster to do it with the allocation call all at once than to set each member to 0 individually. so you don't lose performance in this case

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't do any initialization for you. So when you do:

```
struct list_t *new_list(void){
    struct list_t *list = malloc(sizeof(struct list_t));
    list->length = 0;
    return list;
}
```

`list->head` can be anything.. and probably won't be NULL.

Comment: Thanks **Claudiu**; I'm updating my code now with explicit initialization.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you never set list->tail to *anything*, and then attempt to access list->tail->next if list->head isn't NULL (which, as other have pointed out, isn't guaranteed anyway.)

Comment: Thanks **dlev**; I noticed that half a second after my post. *Whoops!* :)