# calloc(): Do the individual values matter for performance?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, calloc

I'm currently writing an embedded application in C where performance is critical.

Currently, I'm allocating lots of empty memory like this: `calloc(1, num_bytes)` - however, I simply calculate `num_bytes` as the product of a number of items and the size of each item earlier in the code as it's code that used to call `malloc`.

`calloc` seems unique in that it is the only memory allocation function of the -alloc family which takes two arguments for the size. Is there a good reason for doing this? Are there performance implications for specifying different arguments? What was the rationale in choosing this argument layout?

Comment: There probably aren't any noticeable differences, especially not if you enable more advanced optimizations in your compiler.

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581192/how-did-malloc-and-calloc-end-up-with-different-signatures http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536413/why-calloc-takes-two-arguments-while-malloc-only-one

Comment: @Jim - Not exactly duplicates, those are "Why?" questions, where as mine is "Does it matter?"

Comment: You also asked about the rationale. The answer to your question (no, it does not matter) can be found there by careful reading of the rationale.

Answer (score 3):

One advantage of having the separate arguments is that it automatically guards against integer overflow:

```
// On a 32-bit system, the calloc will almost certainly fail, but the malloc
// will succeed to overflow, likely leading to crashes and/or security holes
// (e.g. if the number of items to allocate came from an untrusted source)
void *a = calloc(64, 67108865);  // 2^32/64 + 1
void *b = malloc(64 * 67108865);  // will allocate 64 bytes on 32-bit systems
```

For large allocations, there can also be a performance advantage of doing a `calloc` instead of a `malloc` and `memset` combination, since the `calloc` implementation can use its internal knowledge of the heap to avoid unnecessary work or have improved cache performance.

For example, if the allocator decides to use an OS function such as [`mmap(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) or [`VirtualAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to acquire more virtual address space, that memory will come pre-zeroed for security reasons.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-slower-than-calloc) for a detailed explanation.  For small allocations, you're unlikely to notice much of a difference.

Some `calloc` implementations just call `malloc` and `memset` internally, so there's no advantage other than a potential overflow check.

Comment: Interesting; the Visual Studio 10.0 runtime does do an overflow check.

Comment: @Dietrich: I don't know what version of glibc you're looking at, but in glibc-2.12.2's `malloc/malloc.c`, the implementation of `calloc` in `public_cALLOc` does not look like what you wrote, and it does do an overflow check.

Comment: Indeed so.  I was looking at `cALLOc` not `public_cALLOc`.

Comment: It's not that unlikely ... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-slower-than-calloc

Comment: @Jim: Thanks, that briefly crossed my mind but I didn't think deeply about it.  See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the argument layout of `calloc()` is to allow the allocation of object sizes greater than the storage capacity of a single `size_t` parameter type (which might be as small as 64KiB).

Whether performance is affected depends mostly on how the arguments are passed to `calloc()` in your particular environment. *Usually*, more arguments to pass means more data to be transferred between the caller and the callee -- for example, more arguments will need to be pushed to the callee's stack, yielding a couple of extra instructions to push the arguments in. But I believe that this extra overhead won't be a bottleneck in your program, specially when compared to the execution time of the memory allocator itself.

If you're worried about the performance of `calloc()`, `malloc()` might be faster simply due to the fact that it does not initialize the allocated buffer as `calloc()` do.

Comment: Actually, `calloc` does not always initialize the buffer, it often merely returns memory that is either already zero, or will become zero when it is read.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: True. As always, the particular implementation of an interface might be absolutely different from what we suppose it should be, while still conforming to the documented behavior. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The overhead of passing two arguments rather than one is trivial and surely not what the OP was asking about -- the question was about whether the *values* of the arguments to calloc matter. OTOH, calloc *can* be far faster than malloc + memset, for the reason Dietrich noted.

Comment: This is impossible. `size_t` must be able to store the size of any object, and if `calloc` could allocate objects larger than that, the implementation would be failing to meet the requirements on `size_t`.

Comment: @R..: `size_t` must be able to store the size of any ONE object. `calloc` allocates arrays of objects.

Comment: @Jim Balter: I don't see how it is _surely_ not what the OP was asking about. Actually, I believe this is _precisely_ one of the things he wanted to discuss. Nonetheless, the answer I provided tries to address both of the issues, and it has been clearly stated that the argument passing overhead is the least important of the concerns.

Comment: @R..: As far as I know, your statement is false. `size_t` is the result of a `sizeof` expression. Since `calloc()` returns a pointer, the restrictions on `size_t` do not apply to the pointed-to buffer (since the operator cannot be applied directly to it). I haven't found anything in ISO 9899:1999 (or 1990) saying that the _only_ object sizes allowed by an implementation are restricted to `size_t`. Please direct me if you had.

Comment: @ZanLynx: An array of objects is an object in itself. This is clear per the C standard. I agree however that it's unclear that objects larger than `size_t` are disallowed.

Comment: *Surely* the OP is not concerned about the small number of nanoseconds taken by passing two arguments instead of one, which the OP is *surely* already aware of. The OP stated using `1 * num_bytes` instead of the actual size and number of objects, and wants to know if there's any performance difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm currently writing an embedded application in C where performance
>   is critical.

I think that `calloc` optimization should be pretty low as priority. But try to see whether it's possible to employ `malloc` instead (avoiding the zero-initialization), avoid `alloc` altogether by re-using memory, and possibly allocating memory padded to a platform-specific boundary.

These are all very minor optimization, though (except maybe for `alloc` reuse). I'd focus on the algorithm instead.