# Why do some POSIX functions get a element number and element size parameters?

Tags: c, posix

See:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html

The malloc function simply gets a array size to allocate.

But:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/calloc.html

And:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fread.html

Are just 2 examples of functions that receive element size and number of elements.

Why's that difference? Doesn't it more simple to get a size and that's it?

Comment: It's because of the way they are intended to work, `malloc()` doesn't care about how many elements because it's not doing anything with them, `calloc()` requires this because it initializes every element with `0` so it needs the size of each element, and I think it's pretty obvious why `fread()` wants to know that.

Comment: Post the meaningful parts of your post here,

Comment: @iharob: filling 16 bytes with `0` is the same whether it's four four-byte elements or 16 one-byte elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why calloc takes two arguments while malloc only one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536413/why-calloc-takes-two-arguments-while-malloc-only-one)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555911/why-does-calloc-require-two-parameters-and-malloc-just-one

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a note than a reason, but the values of `size` and `nmemb` do make a difference as far as the return value of `fread(3)` and `fwrite(3)` is concerned. They return the number of elements read or written, where the size of each element is determined by the `size` parameter.

POSIX also says the following re. [`fread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html),

> If a partial element is read, its value is unspecified.

, so in theory the value of `size` could make a difference for the data you get back too when the amount of data read isn't a multiple of `size` (due to end-of-file or errors).

For `calloc()`, the GNU C library (glibc) simply multiplies `size` and `nmemb` together, also checking for overflow (using a trick to quickly detect most `size` and `nmemb` pairs that won't overflow). Here's the relevant code from glibc 2.20 (from `__libc_calloc()` in *malloc/malloc.c*. `nmemb` and `size` are called `n` and  `elem_size`, respectively.):

```
  /* size_t is unsigned so the behavior on overflow is defined.  */
  bytes = n * elem_size;
#define HALF_INTERNAL_SIZE_T \
  (((INTERNAL_SIZE_T) 1) << (8 * sizeof (INTERNAL_SIZE_T) / 2))
  if (__builtin_expect ((n | elem_size) >= HALF_INTERNAL_SIZE_T, 0))
    {
      if (elem_size != 0 && bytes / elem_size != n)
        {
          __set_errno (ENOMEM);
          return 0;
        }
    }
```

`n` and `elem_size` are never referenced after that. `bytes` is used instead.

The `fread()` implementation (`_IO_fread()` in *libio/iofread.c*) similarly multiplies `nmemb` and `size` together and only uses them to calculate the return value after that. (Unlike `calloc()`, it does not check for overflow.)

I'm guessing the reasons for having two parameters might be historical. I would be interested in the answer too. Perhaps the `size` parameter specified the block size of each I/O operation (or served as a hint) at some point for `fread()` and `fwrite()`.

*Update*: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12555996/4577158) answer and the comments has some interesting discussion re. `calloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think in `calloc` and `fread` functions want put values in array's elements so it must put them one by one if it put all of them at one time this may cause problem because your cpu may be in [little-endian] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) order.
for example if you want to set four element into 1 in little-endian machine:

element size = 2 bytes:
| 01 00 | 01 00 | 01 00 | 00 01 |
element size = 3 bytes:
| 01 00 00 | 01 00 00 | 01 00 00 | 01 00 00 |

and for `fread`, It's based on how fread is implemented.
The [Single UNIX Specification says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification)

> For each object, size calls shall be made to the fgetc() function and the results stored, in the order read, in an array of unsigned char exactly overlaying the object.

Comment: Setting the bits in 16 consecutive bytes to all `0s is the same thing whether it's four four-byte elements or 16 one-byte elements. If there is a subtle difference, it requires explanation.

Comment: I add an example into my answer, I think it's better now. thank you.

Comment: That example would be fine for something that let you fill with an arbitrary element value, but `calloc` is fill with bit pattern all 0's.

Comment: I get it now, sorry I was confused it with `memset`. Thank you for pointing that.