# Why does malloc initialize the values to 0 in gcc?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, malloc

Maybe it is different from platform to platform, but

when I compile using gcc and run the code below, I get 0 every time in my ubuntu 11.10.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double *a = malloc(sizeof(double)*100)
    printf("%f", *a);
}
```

Why do malloc behave like this even though there is calloc?

Doesn't it mean that there is an unwanted performance overhead just to initialize the values to 0 even if you don't want it to be sometimes?

---

EDIT: Oh, my previous example was not initiazling, but happened to use "fresh" block.

What I precisely was looking for was why it initializes it when it allocates a large block:

```
int main()
{
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int)*200000);
    a[10] = 3;
    printf("%d", *(a+10));

    free(a);

    a = malloc(sizeof(double)*200000);
    printf("%d", *(a+10));
}

OUTPUT: 3
        0 (initialized)
```

But thanks for pointing out that there is a SECURITY reason when mallocing! (Never thought about it). Sure it has to initialize to zero when allocating fresh block, or the large block.

Comment: For a more realistic test, have you tried allocating, freeing and then allocating again (possibly repeating each multiple times)? Just because malloc returns zero-initialized memory the first time doesn't mean you can count on it in general.

Comment: It also could be that the memory was set to 0 by the operating system or something and `malloc` had nothing to do with it.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 196, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

It doesn't, it just happens to be zero in your case.
(Also your test case doesn't show that the data is zero. It only shows if one element is zero.)

---

**Long Answer:**

When you call `malloc()`, one of two things will happen:

1. It recycles memory that was previous allocated and freed from the same process.
2. It requests new page(s) from the operating system.

In the first case, the memory will contain data leftover from previous allocations. So it won't be zero. This is the usual case when performing small allocations.

In the second case, the memory will be from the OS. This happens when the program runs out of memory - or when you are requesting a very large allocation. (as is the case in your example)

Here's the catch: **Memory coming from the OS will be zeroed for *security* reasons.***

When the OS gives you memory, it could have been freed from a different process. So that memory could contain sensitive information such as a password. So to prevent you reading such data, the OS will zero it before it gives it to you.

<sub>*I note that the C standard says nothing about this. This is strictly an OS behavior. So this zeroing may or may not be present on systems where security is not a concern.</sub>

---

**To give more of a performance background to this:**

As @R. mentions in the comments, this zeroing is why you should always [use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` + `memset()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-slower-than-calloc?lq=1). `calloc()` can take advantage of this fact to avoid a separate `memset()`.

---

On the other hand, this zeroing is sometimes a performance bottleneck. In some numerical applications (such as the [out-of-place FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)), you need to allocate a huge chunk of scratch memory. Use it to perform whatever algorithm, then free it.

*In these cases, the zeroing is unnecessary and amounts to pure overhead.*

The most extreme example I've seen is a 20-second zeroing overhead for a 70-second operation with a 48 GB scratch buffer. (Roughly 30% overhead.)
<sub>(Granted: the machine did have a lack of memory bandwidth.)</sub>

The obvious solution is to simply reuse the memory manually. But that often requires breaking through established interfaces. (especially if it's part of a library routine)

Comment: But you *still* can't count on it being zero unless you do so yourself (or with `calloc`, which does it for you after getting memory from the OS).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Never thought there would be a security issue when mallocing!

Comment: It's subtle. When the OS gives you memory, it could have been freed from a different process. So that memory could contain sensitive information such as a password. So to prevent you reading such data, the OS will zero it before it gives it to you. But it's an implementation detail and may be different such as in some embedded systems.

Comment: This is a bit of an aside from OP's question, but one consequence of this effect is that you should always use `calloc` rather than `malloc`+`memset` when you want zero-initialized memory (at least for large blocks where time to zero could matter). `malloc`+`memset` will always incur a heavy cost of writing to the whole block, but the system's `calloc` can take advantage of the fact that new anonymous memory will be zero-filled to begin with.

Comment: @R.. Well, doesn't the OS perform the same zero loop anyway? When would a previously written page be zeroed, as part of the `free`? Or is there hardware support for this?

Comment: The answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-slower-than-calloc) may help you to understand that.  The kernel can cheat with calloc by not actually writing out all the zeroed-out pages until they are used.  Memset (apparently) forces the pages to be written out immediately.  More info at the link.

Comment: @Mysticial this is actually *wrong* and **harmful information**. It doesn't depend on an embedded system or so, but on the libc implementation and how it reuses memory after freeing, and whether any previous freeing happened in the application. Keyword: page cache (malloc's).

Comment: @mirabilos I said that it *may* be different. I didn't say it *is*. I only mentioned embedded because that's where you're most likely to be in a closed environment disconnected from the outside world where security is not going to matter. In such cases, there is no need for the OS or the libc implementation to zero the memory.

Comment: @Mysticial: mayyyyybe… but still, your comment could be taken by the unwashed masses to mean to not care about “some embedded systems my code is never gonna run on anyway”…

Answer (score 22):

The OS will usually clear fresh memory pages it sends to your process so it can't look at an older process' data. This means that the first time you initialize a variable (or malloc something) it will often be zero but if you ever reuse that memory (by freeing it and malloc-ing again, for instance) then all bets are off.

This inconsistence is precisely why uninitialized variables are such a hard to find bug.

---

As for the unwanted performance overheads, **avoiding unspecified behaviour is probably more important**. Whatever small performance boost you could gain in this case won't compensate the hard to find bugs you will have to deal with if someone slightly modifies the codes (breaking previous assumptions) or ports it to another system (where the assumptions might have been invalid in the first place).

Comment: +1 ... not sure if "probably" is required in the bold text thought ;-)

Answer (score 21):

Why do you assume that `malloc()` initializes to zero? It just so happens to be that the first call to `malloc()` results in a call to `sbrk` or `mmap` system calls, which allocate a page of memory from the OS. The OS is obliged to provide zero-initialized memory for security reasons (otherwise, data from other processes gets visible!). So you might think there - the OS wastes time zeroing the page. But no! In Linux, there is a special system-wide singleton page called the 'zero page' and that page will get mapped as Copy-On-Write, which means that only when you actually write on that page, the OS will allocate another page and initialize it. So I hope this answers your question regarding performance. The memory paging model allows usage of memory to be sort-of lazy by supporting the capability of multiple mapping of the same page plus the ability to handle the case when the first write occurs.

If you call `free()`, the `glibc` allocator will return the region to its free lists, and when `malloc()` is called again, you might get that same region, but dirty with the previous data. Eventually, `free()` might return the memory to the OS by calling system calls again.

Notice that the `glibc` **man page** on `malloc()` strictly says that the memory is not cleared, so by the "contract" on the API, you cannot assume that it does get cleared. Here's the original excerpt:

> malloc() allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.
>   The memory is not cleared.  If size is 0, then malloc() returns either NULL, 
>   or a  unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free().

If you would like, you can read more about of that documentation if you are worried about performance or other side-effects.

Answer (score 16):

I modified your example to contain 2 identical allocations. Now it is easy to see `malloc` doesn't zero initialize memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    {
      double *a = malloc(sizeof(double)*100);
      *a = 100;
      printf("%f\n", *a);
      free(a);
    }
    {
      double *a = malloc(sizeof(double)*100);
      printf("%f\n", *a);
      free(a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output with gcc 4.3.4

```
100.000000
100.000000
```

Comment: I tried what you did and if I only allocate 100 bytes then, even though the pointer points to the SAME address, the value at that address is different. If I allocate 400 bytes or more then both the pointer value and the value in the memory are the same. What do you think could be the cause?

Answer (score 4):

From [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Efficiency-and-Malloc.html#Efficiency-and-Malloc):

> Very large blocks (much larger than a page) are allocated with mmap (anonymous **or via /dev/zero**) by this implementation.

Comment: The OP is mallocing in small steps though. Does that reference you found have anything about that too?

Answer (score 2):

The standard does not dictate that `malloc()` should initialize the values to zero. It just happens at your platform that it might be set to zero, or it might have been zero at the specific moment you read that value.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't demonstrate that `malloc` initialises its memory to 0. That could be done by the operating system, before the program starts. To see shich is the case, write a different value to the memory, free it, and call malloc again. You will probably get the same address, but you will have to check this. If so, you can look to see what it contains. Let us know!

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` **doesn't initialize memory to zero**. It returns it to you as it is without touching the memory or changing its value.

So, why do we get those zeros?

Before answering this question we should understand **how malloc works**:

When you call malloc it checks whether the `glibc` allocator has a memory of the requested size or not.

**If it does**, it will return this memory to you. This memory usually comes due to a previous `free` operation so **it has garbage value**(maybe zero or not) in most cases.

On the other hand, **if it can't find memory**, it will **ask the OS to allocate memory** for it, by calling `sbrk` or `mmap` system calls.
The OS returns a zero-initialized page for security reasons as this memory may have been used by another process and carries valuable information such as passwords or personal data.

You can read about it yourself from this [Link](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_node/libc_29.html):

> Neighboring chunks can be coalesced on a free no matter what their
> size is. This makes the implementation suitable for all kinds of
> allocation patterns without generally incurring high memory waste
> through fragmentation.

> Very large blocks (much larger than a page) are allocated with mmap
> (anonymous or via /dev/zero) by this implementation

In some implementations `calloc` [uses this property of the OS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1538427/14043328) and asks the OS to allocate pages for it to make sure the memory is always zero-initialized without initializing it itself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that it is definitely being initialised? Is it possible that the area returned by malloc() just frequently has 0 at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

Never **ever** count on **any** compiler to generate code that will initialize memory to anything.  malloc simply returns a pointer to n bytes of memory *someplace* hell it might even be in swap.

If the contents of the memory is critical initialize it yourself.

Comment: Except in cases where the language guarantees that it will be initialized.  Static objects without explicit initialization are implicitly initialized to zero.