# How to initialize a dynamic int array elements to 0 in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I created a dynamic array ,and i need to initialize all the members to 0.
How can this be done in C?

```
   int* array;
    array = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In this case you would use `calloc()`:

```
array = (int*) calloc(n, sizeof(int));
```

<strike>It's safe to assume that all systems now have all zero bits as the representation for zero.</strike>

§6.2.6.2 guarantees this to work:

> For any integer type, the object representation where all the bits are
>   zero shall be a representation of the value zero in that type.

It's also possible to do a combination of `malloc()` + `memset()`, but for reasons discussed in the [comments of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029584/why-does-malloc-initialize-the-values-to-0-in-gcc/8029624#8029624), it is likely to be more efficient to use `calloc()`.

Comment: It's more than "safe to assume", I'd say that it's actually guaranteed by §6.2.6.2.

Comment: @Mysticial it is guaranteed by the standard (C99, 6.2.6.2p5) "For any integer type, the object representation where all the bits are zero shall be a representation of the value zero in that type."

Comment: Yes, you are right, I found the line that says this. Adding to my answer.

Comment: Value bits => "Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as the same bit in the object representation of the corresponding unsigned type"; Sign bits => "If the sign bit is zero, it shall not affect the resulting value." Padding bits aren't relevant.

Comment: The cast is unnecessary too in C.

Comment: @MatteoItalia sorry, I didn't have your answer displayed when I responded

Comment: @Mat Correct, it's not necessary. I was mainly trying to preserve the OP's sample. Though the cast can still be useful if the code is ever ported to C++.

Comment: @Mysticial: I'd hope conversion to C++ would get rid of that `malloc` altogether and replace it with proper containers :)

Answer (score 7):

```
memset(array, 0, n*sizeof(int));
```

Or alternatively, you could allocate your block of memory using `calloc`, which does this for you:

```
array = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
```

`calloc` documentation:

> **void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);**
>
> The  **calloc()**  function allocates memory for an array of *nmemb* elements of *size* bytes each  and returns a pointer to the allocated memory. The memory is set to zero. ...

Answer (score 4):

Use `calloc` function ([usage example](https://ideone.com/QaET1)):

```
int *array = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
```

From [`calloc` reference page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/calloc.html):

> `void *calloc(size_t nelem, size_t elsize);`
>
> The `calloc()` function shall allocate unused space for an array of `nelem` elements each of whose size in bytes is `elsize`. **The space shall be initialized to all bits 0.**

Answer (score 0):

```
memset(array, 0, n * sizeof *array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    for (i=0; i<x; ++i){
                        array[i]=0;
                    }
```

That should do the trick. I guess you have to make a loop that makes 0 every element in the array. Memset could also work for you.

Comment: Hey, you do not have to write a program that is interactively proving the answer correct. Finding the one line that does the trick in this source is way harder...

Comment: @dgunchev Yes you are right but i was just writing something similar in c arm when i saw the question by chance and thought about a fast answer. :)