# Can I shorten a CUDA allocated buffer?

Tags: cuda

I'm implementing an algorithm on the GPU using CUDA which is certain to give incorrect results when a specific input buffer (3D float vectors) contains duplicate entries. For this reason I want to do a pre-processing step to remove any duplicates which are present.

Since I know the input data contains a significant number of duplicates, explicitly trimming the buffer can free up much needed memory for some of the processing steps. Since I have a lot of data to work with, I intend to do this in place within the already allocated buffer.

Does CUDA have a mechanism which allows the end of a `cudaMalloc()`'d buffer to be trimmed and freed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking about is the equivalent of a "realloc" function, and no such functionality exists in either the runtime or driver APIs.

Also note that `cudaMalloc` and `cudaFree` probably [do not work the way you might imagine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10394755/681865), and freeing memory will [not necessarily change the amount of available free memory on the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100615/cudafree-is-not-freeing-memory).