# Which is fastest for zeroing-out an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, optimization

The question title is quite self-explanatory. I have an run loop that need a dynamic-sized array. But I do know the maximum of that size is going to be, so if needed, I can max it out instead of dynamically-sizing it.

Here's my code, I know that clock_t probably not the best choice for timing in terms of portability, but clock_t provide bad accuracy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>

#define TEST_SIZE 1000000

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int* arrayPtr = NULL;
    int  array[TEST_SIZE];
    int  it = 0;

    clock_t begin, end;

    begin = clock();
    memset(array, 0, sizeof(int) * TEST_SIZE);
    end = clock();
    cout << "Time to memset: "<< end - begin << endl;

    begin = clock();
    fill(array, array + TEST_SIZE, 0);
    end = clock();
    cout << "Time to fill: "<< end - begin << endl;

    begin = clock();
    for ( it = 0 ; it < TEST_SIZE ; ++ it ) array[it] = 0;
    end = clock();
    cout << "Time to for: "<< end - begin << endl;
}
```

Here's my result:

```
Time to memset: 1590
Time to fill: 2334
Time to for: 2371
```

Now that I know new & delete does now zero-out the array, is there any way faster than these?

Please help me!

Comment: `new` and `delete` aren't the same as zeroing an array. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I do not know why profile the delete operator.
Anyway, new operator does not 0-fill the array.

Comment: Really, my system always give me an initialized array of 0s.

Comment: @ShaneHsu See this question for an explanation for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029584/why-does-malloc-initialize-the-values-to-0-in-gcc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you are comparing apples and oranges.

`memset` and the for-loop explicitly set the memory content to a particular value(*in your example `0`*). While, the `new` merely allocates sufficient memory(*atleast as requested*) and `delete` merely marks the memory free for reuse. There is no change in the content at that memory. So `new` and `delete` do not initialize/de-initialize the actual memory content.
Technically, the content in that memory has an ***Indeterminate value***. Quite literally, the values maybe anything and you cannot rely on them to be anything specific.They might be `0` but they are not guaranteed to be. In fact using these values will cause your program to have an ***Undefined Behavior***.

A `new` call for an class does two things:

- Allocates requested memory &
- Calls constructor for the class to initialize the object.

But note that in your case the type is an `int` and there is no default initialization for `int`.

Answer (score 2):

`new` only allocates a memory block, it doesn't initialize the allocated memory.
To initialize an array you can use `memset()` or do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Good compiler will optimize all 4 approaches into 1 call of `memset`. Also, what's the difference between 3<sup>rd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> approach?

You can also do

```
int  array[TEST_SIZE] = {};
```

gain readability and save 1 line of code.

Comment: actually nothing, it's just something to play with.

Answer (score 0):

I would resort to `memset` in this case. `fill` is generic, but the platform can offer you some really nice tricks in its implementation of `memset`. This is possible, because the function is unambigous in what it does and dumb enough:

- It could employ (S)DMA for actual memory modification, which could have faster interface to memories. Also, while it runs the task, the CPU could do something else
- When it knows it has to sequentially write contiguous memory region, it could do something preventive about cache invalidation
- The implementation in ARM-based embedded systems can benefit from [burst mode](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3491.html); it is realized with special assembler instruction (STMFD, STMFA etc.) and in this mode 3 writes are equal two normal writes timewise

Comment: fill for array of integers should be implemented via 1 memset anyways.