# Fox Algorithm with MPI

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, parallel-processing, mpi

I am coding an implementation for Fox Algorithm with MPI in C. 
I already subdivised my global_matrix into smaller blocks. So each process has a little block of matrix A and matrix B. 
However I have trouble understanding how to implement Fox algorithm : a lot of code found on the internet are doing the following.

[Implementation for Fox Algorithm](http://users.abo.fi/mats/PP2012/handouts/Matrixmult.pdf)

What I don't understand : In the last slides, there is C code that should implement the algorithm. But it seems that the temp array is never properly initialized and thus should result in weird behaviours when used in MPI_Bcast() and in the matrix multiplication.

I think I have the algo almost working but my result values are definitely wrong.

(I can provide code if you need)

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not answering your original question can I just remark that `MPI_Bcast` and `matrixmult` both take `tmp` as a first argument in the `else` block, perhaps using it as a destination to store variables.

Without seeing how those two functions are implemented you can't know for sure whether `tmp` is used unitialised.

Also [`malloc`-allocated memory can sometimes be 0 initalised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029584/why-does-malloc-initialize-the-values-to-0-in-gcc%20though) though it's not behaviour I would rely on.

And finally, if you're going to use the code in the slides [don't cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.
Will try to make it work. If I succeed (which I doubt :P), I'll post what helped me.

Comment: Happy to help, yeah sure, please post some code once you get something working, if I can't help others would be more than able to :)

Answer (score 1):

So I have found a solution to my problem almost after I asked the question.
Just to be exhaustive, I've pushed the code to github. Remember that's a school project and that it's not completely finished and correct. Also the comments may be a bit weird : I'm not a native English speaker. 
[My code on github](https://github.com/sgerin/mpi-gemm)

Nobilis had the answer : MPI_Bcast isn't just a function to send data but also to receive some. The MPI_Bcast should be called by every processus that should receive data and by the sender. 
That is if I write.

```
int* int_array = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
int root = 0;

if(my_rank == 0)
{
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        int_array[i] = i;
}

MPI_Bcast(int_array, 10, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

This code means : for each processus started by MPI allocate 10 int. Then, only for processus of rank 0, put some valid data in the previous allocated array.
Then each processus calls MPI_Bcast with the same arguments : the memory where data should be written (or from where it should be sent in the case of my_rank == 0), size and type of the data (is it an array or just one int ?), you define the root who will send the data to every process found in MPI_COMM_WORLD.

That's why we don't care if int_array isn't initialized in most process (except for the process having my_rank == root).

Note that you can use MPI_Datatype to send data in a specific layout. 
If so, you should be read about :

- MPI_Type_create_subarray
- MPI_Type_create_resized
- MPI_Type_commit

Hope that can help someone.