# what is the default value after malloc in c?

Tags: c, malloc

I have the following code:

```
int *p;

p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
```

but what is the default value of this int array with 10 elements? are all of them 0?

Comment: Why not read the manual page - http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc

Comment: First few lines "Description

The malloc() function allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to the allocated memory. The memory is not initialized. "

Comment: [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 14):

The real content is indeterminate.

> #### C11, § 7.22.3.4 The `malloc` function
>
> The `malloc` function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size and
>   whose **value is indeterminate**.

However, the operating system often initializes this memory space to 0 (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8029624/1126268)). You can use rather `calloc` to be sure that every bits are setted to 0.

Answer (score 5):

```
are all of them 0?
```

No, `malloc` does not initialize the memory allocated, use `calloc` in order to initialize all values to `0`

```
int *p;
p = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's undefined. Using `calloc( )` instead then the allocated buffer is defined to be filled with binary 0

Answer (score 1):

The "default" value of an element created with malloc is the value stored at this point in your memory (often 0 but you can have other values, if an another program wrote in this place).
You can use calloc, or after the malloc, you can memset your var.
And don't forget to verify the value of your pointer, check if it's not NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [calloc()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/calloc.html) for this purpose. malloc() allocats only memory, so this memory contains garbage values by default.