# Matrix product cause error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c, matrix, syntax-error

I have a Java method that multiplies 2 matrices. I have tried to port the same method in C without success.

Here is my attempt to write a method that should multiply 2 matrices in C:

```
float **multiply(int m1, int n1, float Xy1[], int m2, int n2, float Xy2[]) {
    int i, j, k;
    float **result = allocate_mem_mtrx(m1, n2);
    for (i = 0; i < m1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < n1; k++) {
                result[i][j] = result[i][j] + Xy1[i][k] * Xy2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

At this line

```
result[i][j] = result[i][j] + Xy1[i][k] * Xy2[k][j];
```

I receive the error:

`subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector`

Clearly my syntax is wrong, but I haven't understood how I should fix this line of code, to solve my  problem.

In my main I have:

```
float matrix1[3][2] = {{0, 1}, {3, 4}, {6, 7}};
float matrix2[2][3] = {{5, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}};
```

with the actual signature I invoke the method in this way:

```
multiply(3, 2, &matrix1, 2, 3, &matrix2);
```

---

My original Java method

```
public static int[][] multiply(int[][] Xy1, int[][] Xy2) {
    int rowsInXy1 = Xy1.length;
    int columnsInXy1 = Xy1[0].length; // same as rows in B
    int columnsInXy2 = Xy2.length;
    int[][] result = new int[rowsInXy1][columnsInXy2];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsInXy1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnsInXy2; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < columnsInXy1; k++) {
                result[i][j] = result[i][j] + Xy1[i][k] * Xy2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `matrix in C`, but you tagged this as `C++`.  A C++ solution would have used `std::vector` or equivalent container, and not float** or use functions such as `allocate_mem_mtrx`.

Comment: ops sorry... maybe I have clicked pn the wrong suggested tag

Comment: @Wolf the question is about a porting problem, not a math problem, the math problem is yet solved and is also shown the algorithm, and the question respect all the Stackoverflow guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `float Xy1[]`

but you treat it as 2D

`Xy1[i][k]`

Same for `Xy2`.

You should change `float Xy1[]` to `float** Xy1`.

Also another thing, in your loop I feel that you are sure that `result` 2D array is initialized in your function that says allocate. If that functions just `malloc`s the array, then this array will have **garbage** inside.
For [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029584/why-does-malloc-initialize-the-values-to-0-in-gcc).

[EDIT]

Also I see in one other answer that they *cast what `malloc` returns*. Ouch!

[Do not cast the return value of `malloc` in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

[EDIT.2]

SO, you could something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

// We return the pointer
float **get(int N, int M) /* Allocate the array */
{
    /* Check if allocation succeeded. (check for NULL pointer) */
    int i;
    float **table;
    table = malloc(N*sizeof(float *));
    for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
        table[i] = malloc( M*sizeof(float) );
    return table;
} 

void free2Darray(int** p, int N) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
        free(p[i]);
    free(p);
}

// do not forget to FREE what multiply returns
float **multiply(int m1, int n1, float** Xy1,int m2, int n2, float** Xy2) {
    int i,j,k;
    float **result = get(m1,n2);
    for (i = 0; i < m1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < n1; k++) {
                // this line is correct, the prototype of the function
                // was not OK
                result[i][j] = result[i][j] + Xy1[i][k] * Xy2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
int main(void) {
  float** A = get(5, 5); // arrays declared as double pointers
  float** B = get(5, 5);
  float** C = get(5, 5);

  C = multiply(5, 5, A, 5, 5, B);

  // free2Darray function defined below
  free2Darray(A, 5);
  free2Darray(B, 5);
  free2Darray(C, 5);

  return 0;
}
```

[EDIT.3]

Another way, if you now the columns apriori, which you probably don't as your function implies, you could do that:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// We return the pointer
float **get(int N, int M) /* Allocate the array */
{
    /* Check if allocation succeeded. (check for NULL pointer) */
    int i;
    float **table;
    table = malloc(N*sizeof(float *));
    for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
        table[i] = malloc( M*sizeof(float) );
    return table;
}

float **multiply(int m1, int n1, float Xy1[][2],int m2, int n2, float Xy2[][2]) {
    int i,j,k;
    float **result = get(m1,n2);
    for (i = 0; i < m1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < n1; k++) {
                result[i][j] = result[i][j] + Xy1[i][k] * Xy2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
int main() {
  float matrix1[2][2] = {{0, 1}, {3, 4}};
  float matrix2[2][2] = {{0, 1}, {3, 4}};
  float** C;

  C = multiply(2, 2, matrix1, 2, 2, matrix2);

  free2Darray(C, 2);

  printf("ok\n");

  return 0;
}
```

I got the `get()` function from my [pseudo-site](http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/2d-dynamic-array-c/).

Comment: emmm... where I have casted malloc returns? 
If I change the signature I get problem on the method invocation, Basically I need only to know how I have to rewrite this line `result[i][j] = result[i][j] + Xy1[i][k] * Xy2[k][j];` in the correct way.

Comment: You should change how you call the function then @AndreaF! How do u call it? I am talking about another answer that cast what malloc returns!

Comment: @AndreaF I think you had a problem regarding how you declare your arrays in main (or the calling function), see my edit!

Comment: In my main I have `float matrix1[3][2] = {{0, 1}, {3, 4}, {6, 7}};
    float matrix2[2][3] = {{5, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}};`

with the actual signature I invoke the method in this way `multiply(3,2,&matrix1,2,3, &matrix2);`

If I try to change the signature as suggested how should I invoke the method correctly? If I write `multiply(3,2,matrix1,2,3, matrix2);` the program crash at start

Comment: See my edit @AndreaF, copy paste it and report back please! :)

Comment: thanks, the second way seems works, but not always know the matrix columns a priori and the method should works for any nxn matrix. see my question updated.

Comment: Your updated code gives that:
../main.c:46:3: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘multiply’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
../main.c:16:9: note: expected ‘float **’ but argument is of type ‘float (*)[2]’
../main.c:46:3: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘multiply’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
../main.c:16:9: note: expected ‘float **’ but argument is of type ‘float (*)[3]’

Comment: @AndreaF if you want to work for nxn, I suggest using the approach that dynamically allocated/dellaoctes the arrays. This is the way to go in C!

Comment: Yes I know. How should I fix this?

Comment: @AndreaF you can't. Either you go by the way that specifies the column, which is restricting, or you go by the way of dynamic allocation. Both methods are explained above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54241/discussion-between-g-samaras-and-andreaf).

Answer (score 1):

```
float Xy1[]
```

is not a two dimensional array, so to write

```
Xy1[i][k]
```

is an error.

In C you can use a pointer to pointer notation:

```
float** multiply( int m1, int n1, float** Xy1,int m2, int n2, float** Xy2) {
    //...
}
```

or you can take advantage of the variable-length array feature in the C language and write
functions that can take multidimensional arrays of varying sizes:

```
float** multiply( int m1, int n1, float Xy1[m1][n1],
                                       int m2, int n2, float Xy2[m2][n2]) {
        float **result, i, j;

        result = malloc( m1 * sizeof *result);  // remember to free this memory

        for( i = 0; i < m1; ++i)
            result[i] =  malloc( n2 * sizeof float);

        //... I don't continue since there seems to be an issue with your indices
        // however now you can use result this way:
        // result[i][j] = result[i][j] + Xy1[i][k] * Xy2[k][j]; i, j, k integers
        return result;
}
```

In C++ use a `std::vector< std::vector<float> >`:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<float> > array;  // shorten notation

array multiply( const array& Xy1, const array& Xy2) {
    //...
}
```

In addition

```
int[][] result = new int[rowsInXy1][columnsInXy2];
```

is not correct way to create two dimensional array. Such array is an array of pointers and correct way to create this is:

C

```
int **a, i;

a = malloc( rowsInXy1 * sizeof *a);

for( i = 0; i < rowsInXy1; ++i)
    a[i] =  malloc( columnsInXy2 * sizeof int);
```

C++

```
int** result = new int*[rowsInXy1];
for( int i = 0; i < rowsInXy1; ++i)
    result[i] = new int[columnsInXy2];
```

Comment: Do NOT cast what `malloc` returns. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: I'm in C not in C++. The Java version method is to clarify my purpose . Basically I need only to know how I have to rewrite this line `result[i][j] = result[i][j] + Xy1[i][k] * Xy2[k][j];` in the correct way in my posted c method

Comment: @AndreaF after applying my suggests you can write result[i][j] = result[i][j] + Xy1[i][k] * Xy2[k][j];

Answer (score 0):

I see you have already chosen a solution but here is some additional info about arrays in C.

In C there is no equivalent of Java's `int[][]` type. Java array storage also includes storage of how many items are in the array. However, C's array storage is purely the values in the array contiguous in memory; and you have to keep track of the size either as compile-time constants, or by storing a variable that holds the length.

Further; originally in C, arrays (using the `[]` syntax) had to have their size known at compile-time. There is an optional feature called *variable-length array* which means that the array size can be specified at runtime -- however the size can't be changed once the array is created.  The major compiler vendors all support VLA, I think.

The VLA uses contiguous storage, however it is not possible to return one via a function's return value. But you can "return" them using an "out" parameter.

It's probably going to turn into a jumble if your code sometimes uses VLAs and sometimes uses dynamically-allocated arrays of pointers.

Another point: in both cases you have to store both array dimensions separately from the array, so that's 3 variables to pass around for each matrix. I'd like to suggest wrapping all of this up in a struct. Since VLAs can't live in a struct, and the compiler might not support them anyway, your best bet may be to use the dynamic allocation version.

Even though we are in C, if you are planning to do more than just a throwaway program, my recommendation would be to use an object-oriented approach for the matrix. Here's an example framework (where all Matrices are to have the Matrix be dynamically allocated, as well as the cells):

```
// Matrix.h
typedef struct
{
    size_t y_dim, x_dim;
    float **cells;
} Matrix;

Matrix *matrix_construct(size_t y_dim, size_t x_dim);
void matrix_free(Matrix *m);     // frees m as well as cells

void matrix_assign(Matrix *dst, Matrix const *src);   // may re-size dst
void matrix_set_values(Matrix *dst, float *row_major);
bool matrix_is_equal(Matrix const *m1, Matrix const *m2);   

typedef Matrix *MatrixBinaryOperator(Matrix const *m1, Matrix const *m2);
MatrixBinaryOperator matrix_multiply;
```

Example usage:

```
float mat1_array[3][2] = {{0, 1}, {3, 4}, {6, 7}};
float mat2_array[2][3] = {{5, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}; 

Matrix *mat1 = matrix_construct(3, 2);
Matrix *mat2 = matrix_construct(2, 3);
matrix_set_values(mat1, (float *)&mat1_array);
matrix_set_values(mat2, (float *)&mat2_array);

Matrix *mat3 = matrix_multiply(mat1, mat2);

matrix_free(mat1);    
matrix_free(mat2);    
matrix_free(mat3);
```

[See it working](http://ideone.com/xmdozD) - disclaimer: this code doesn't check for malloc failure and I have only done the most basic testing; and a lot of optimization is possible.