# When we call (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)) to allocate memory for a string, is it initialized? How to initialize?

Tags: c, pointers, initialization

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char)); 
strcpy(str, ""); //Does this line initialize str to an empty string?
```

After calling line 1, does the allocated memory contain garbage? What about after calling line 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does malloc initialize the values to 0 in gcc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029584/why-does-malloc-initialize-the-values-to-0-in-gcc)

Comment: `man malloc` will tell you.

Comment: Consider using [strdup](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) or [asprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) if your system have them..

Comment: the expression: `sizeof(char)`  is defined by the standard to be 1 and multiplying by 1 has absolutely no effect on the parameter passed to malloc().   All it does is clutter the code.

Comment: if you want the malloc'd memory to be initialized to all '\0's then use `calloc()` rather than `malloc()`.   In all cases, check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   In C, do not cast the returned value, because it is a `void*` type so can be assigned to any pointer.  casting the returned value just clutters the code and creates headaches when maintenance is performed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> After calling line 1, does the allocated memory contain garbage?

It can contain anything, since `malloc` per the standard isn't required to initialize the memory, and hence in most implementations shouldn't either. It will most likely just contain whatever data the previous "user" of that memory put there.

> What about after calling line 2?

With that instruction you're copying a `\0` character with "byte value" 0 to the first byte of the allocated memory. Everything else is still untouched. You could as well have done `str[0] = '\0'` or even `*str = '\0'`. All of these options makes `str` point at an "empty string".

Note also that, since you tagged the question `C` and not `C++`, that casting the return value from `malloc` is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

malloc just provides a memory location creates a pointer to it and returns that. Initialization will not happen. You might get a junk value if the same memory was occupied by other stuff before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `malloc` returns uninitialized memory, and yes, your second line of code initializes your memory to an empty string.