# Dynamic memory allocation after scanf

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-allocation

Is it possible to have dynamic memory allocation in a string that is read with scanf without first declaring it as an array?

Comment: Yes. Allocate it and pass the pointer to `fscanf`. And yet `fscanf` still isn't safe.

Comment: exactly, i mean scanf!

Comment: `scanf` on most implementations is just a call to `vfscanf(stdin, ...)` So what applies to one, applies to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to dynamically allocate memory for a `string` ***after*** having read it with `scanf`, as `scanf` needs a pointer. This means that you must allocate memory first, in order to give it as an argument to `scanf`.

You can do this like the following example :

```
char *str;
str = malloc(X*sizeof(char)); //where x is the number of characters you want to allocate
if (str != NULL)
    int result = scanf("%s", str);
```

In other words, pass the allocated pointer to `scanf`.

***Note*** : You should be careful about the input you give, as you might cause a [buffer-overflow](/questions/tagged/buffer-overflow) if you give a string which is larger than the allocated space.

Comment: exactly, i mean scanf!

Comment: @AlterMann: `malloc` may return null on embedded systems, but on a PC, it will never do that, unless you exhaust the full address space.

Comment: @StamatisPapadopoulos could you please clarify your comment? I did not understand if I covered you or not.

Comment: @KarstenKoop, and what about limiting the amount of available memory per user with [ulimit](http://tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/x4733.html)? to be portable always check the result of `malloc`

Comment: @StamatisPapadopoulos no, it is not possible to dynamically allocate memory for a string *after* having read it. I will update my post for you :)

Comment: @AlterMann it only makes sense to check if you have a strategy to handle the out-of-memory condition. Otherwise it's better and simpler to just let the program crash.

Comment: Let the program crash? Without a diagnosis? Without a log? Nothing? No, thank you.

Comment: @Marievi, έχω και κάποιες άλλες απορίες, αν μπορούσες να με βοηθήσεις. -Ευχαριστώ- :)

Comment: @Marievi η malloc aρχικοποιεί τις τιμές 0, και πότε πρέπει να την αρχικοποιώ;

Comment: @StamatisPapadopoulos, no malloc does *not* initialize to zero, please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029584/why-does-malloc-initialize-the-values-to-0-in-gcc). Did you confuse it with [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/)? Moreover, please notice that you are in an International site, the top for programming, thus comments fully written in Greek, is not a good approach. Ευχαριστώ! :)

Answer (score 0):

From your question is seems you want to allocate the memory for the string **after** it has been scanned in. Unfortunately you are not able to do this as the `scanf` functions needs memory addresses to put the data that it scans in. The best you will be able to do is this:

```
char *someInput = malloc(sizeof(char) * 80);
scanf("%s", someInput);
```

Edit: note the 80 is an arbitrary amount, this represents how many characters we are allocating for our string to hold - 80 was chosen as it the usual length of a line in a command prompt.

Comment: you mean that if i don't use array then the scanf doesn't know where to put the data?

Comment: @StamatisPapadopoulos precisely, you need to scan the data into some place in memory right? declaring just means "i have this variable of this type" until you allocate memory for it it's simply just a name. Its important for the answers here that you also understand the relationship between arrays and pointers in c.

Comment: if a have a pointer declared then i don't have the right amount of memory, right?

Comment: @StamatisPapadopoulos Thats is not the case. A pointer can point to as much memory you allocate for it for example in my answer the point is pointing to 80 char's worth of memory. A pointer and an array are extremely similar in c, in a lot of cases they are used interchangeably. An array can be seen (and used) as a pointer with each consecutive element following the first. This is a crucial topic in c and its important you go off and do some reading on it - I wouldn't do it justice explaining it in the comments. Also don't forget the accept the answer you found most helpful.

Comment: @StamatisPapadopoulos glad i could help, on stack overflow you can only accept one answer, also you should upvote answers you found helpful!