# Malloc or Calloc and when

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c difference between malloc and calloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538420/c-difference-between-malloc-and-calloc)

Is calloc same as malloc with memset?? or is there any difference

> char *ptr;
>   ptr=(char *)calloc(1,100)

```
  or
```

> char *ptr;
>   ptr=(char *) malloc(100);
>   memset(ptr,0,100);

Comment: If you have a *nix platform, type `man calloc` into a terminal.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-slower-than-calloc

Comment: Also, don't cast the return value of `malloc()` (et al).

Comment: @asbumste: You shouldn't use `malloc` in C++ anyway.

Comment: @asbumste A question should **not** be tagged C and C++ at the same time, because they're completely different languages. "C and C++" is *not* a language.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of "What is the difference between calloc and malloc?". The question is "Is calloc, malloc + memset ?"

Comment: @log0: The former answers the latter.

Answer (score 2):

This is how `calloc` is defined by gcc:

```
PTR
calloc (size_t nelem, size_t elsize)
{
  register PTR ptr;

  if (nelem == 0 || elsize == 0)
    nelem = elsize = 1;

  ptr = malloc (nelem * elsize);

  if (ptr) bzero (ptr, nelem * elsize);

  return ptr;
}
```

http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/libiberty/calloc.c?view=markup

with

```
void
bzero (void *to, size_t count)
{
  memset (to, 0, count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As result, it's the same .

Both are allocating memory and then set it to 0

Comment: I said **as result** for the example he gave

Comment: No, you said "as result". :P

Comment: @netcoder Could you elaborate? I don't see what you're trying to get at.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I could, but I won't, because the question is closed and useless anyway.

Comment: @DanielFischer there are tons of other examples where the result would be different. Anything where this sizeof() isn't 1.

Comment: @asbumste Sure, there's a difference between `ptr = calloc(nmemb, size);` and `ptr = malloc(nmemb*size); memset(ptr,0,nmemb);`. But with `memset(ptr, 0, nmemb*size);` the result is the same. The assumption that the multiplication with `size` has been omitted on principle, and not because `size == 1` here, seems a bit daring.