# Pointers and Arrays in C language

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am by no means a master of the C language, nor am i going to claim to be. But I was pretty sure I understood pointers until I came across these two very different implementations that the author claimed would have the same outcome. Im just not seeing it. Can somebody please explain to me what each of these are doing?

```
int (*AA)[4];
AA = malloc(sizeof(int[4])*size);
```

and the 2nd one:

```
int *BB;
BB = (int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
```

From my current understanding, If i wanted to make the 2nd one in c++, it is equivalent to:

```
int *CC;
CC=new int[size]
```

Is this assumption Correct?

Comment: What do you expect them to do?

Comment: they by no means have the same outcome

Comment: They don't do the same thing; they involve different types.

Comment: the first is a pointer to an array of 4 int. The second is a pointer of int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comments notwithstanding,  Given your code:

[image]

For illustration, here is what is shown when in debug mode looking at what was created:  (ANSI C99 compiler, 32bit build)

[image]

At the very least, *understanding fully what your author meant* when stating *same outcome* is important.
***Also illustrates why*** the use of `calloc()` as opposed to `malloc()` might be a good option (C99).

***The second part question:*** *C++ version*

```
int* BB = new int[size];
```

is valid.

Comment: In C99, main's return can be omitted;  calloc is entirely unrelated (especially looking at the copy-on-write semantics common implementations use with calloc()'ed buffers); does your answer imply that the storage pointed to by AA is in fact only 4 ints large? Finally, I'm not aware of an ANSI C99 compiler for windows -- which one is it?

Comment: @fstd - ***First***, my answer is not intended to stand in disagreement with any other. Its intent is to _illustrate_ what memory looked like when OP variables compiled and run. (as it does)  ***Second***, agree'd, comment on `calloc()`-`malloc()` is not related to main thrust of OP.  Just an observation (preference really) on my part that space provided my `malloc()` _always_ contains unwanted values, as such, I typically caution people of that, and suggest `calloc()` as an alternative. (see next comment for remainder)

Comment: @fstd - ***third*** _does your answer imply...?_ As I mentioned, it _illustrates_ what memory looks like for the two variable arrays after compile and run.  ***Forth*** ***[CLANG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)*** - which supports all C99 features, except floating point pragmas.

Comment: First, I didn't say it would.  Second, that's kind of what i was getting at - calloc() is /not/ the same as malloc()+memset()-to-zero (therefore i would avoid suggesting people to use it as such);  Third, then I don't understand what we're looking at, in that image. Could you please explain?

Comment: @fstd - Two screen shots, 1) the execution being stopped just after all calls to allocate memory in my editor. 2) A view of size (== 4) AA located at 0x024A0080 & BB located at 0x024A00D0, both created on the heap using malloc().   ***Regarding*** the `malloc() - Calloc comment you made, it interested me so I did some reading, including ***[HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538420/difference-between-malloc-and-calloc)***.  AndreyT's comment in particular mirrors your concern.  Thanks for bringing it up, I am a convert.

Comment: actually it's @AshishChavan's and @SnappleLVR's answers which `mirror my concern'.  Sickening to see wrong answers upvoted way above 100...

Comment: @fstd in Standard C, calloc is the same as malloc+memset. The OP asked about "C language" and did not put any OS-specific tags. If a particular platform has other differences then it's good to mention them but you should also clearly state that you are referring to a particular platform (and, if possible, also list which other platforms have the same behaviour).

Answer (score 3):

First part:
`int (*AA)[4];` defines AA to be a pointer to an int[4].

`AA = malloc(sizeof(int[4])*size);` allocates storage for `size` `int[4]`s

Second part:
`int *BB;` defines BB to be a pointer to an int.

`BB = (int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int));` allocates  storage for `size` `int`s, then unnecessarily casts the result, thereby introducing a potential error you won't get warned about (namely, if the prototype for malloc() is not in scope).

Therefore, the result is arguably different

Comment: The first one allocates 4 times as much space as the second one, so I would say they are very different

Comment: as different as your comment is redundant ;)