# Performance: memset

Tags: c, performance, memory-management

I have simple C code that does this (pseudo code):

```
#define N 100000000
int *DataSrc = (int *) malloc(N);
int *DataDest = (int *) malloc(N);
memset(DataSrc, 0, N);
for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
    StartTimer();
    memcpy(DataDest, DataSrc, N);
    StopTimer();
}
printf("%d\n", DataDest[RandomInteger]);
```

My PC: Intel Core i7-3930, with 4x4GB DDR3 1600 memory running RedHat 6.1 64-bit.

The first `memcpy()` occurs at 1.9 GB/sec, while the next three occur at 6.2 GB/s.
The buffer size (`N`) is too big for this to be caused by cache effects.  So, my first Question:

- Why is the first `memcpy()` so much slower? Maybe `malloc()` doesn't fully allocate the memory until you use it?

If I eliminate the `memset()`, then the first `memcpy()` runs at about 1.5 GB/sec,
but the next three run at 11.8 GB/sec.  Almost 2x speedup.  My second question:

- Why is `memcpy()` 2x faster if I don't call `memset()`?

Comment: Isn't it UB if you memcpy from an uninitialized source? What compiler are you using with what optimizations? Make the timings more reliably by increasing data size by 10x or more.

Comment: @usr The data will be random, there is no ub as long as you don't use the data in a way that could introduce ub. There is no code in the example that would do that.

Comment: I'm using gcc with -O2.

Comment: @self. sounds to me like reading an uninitialized variable which alone is enough to trigger UB.

Comment: BTW: 11.8GB/s busspeed seems a bit too fast to me.

Comment: @usr Reading uninitialized variable doesn't trigger ub, using that value incorrectly does. For example using that value to access an array offset will trigger ub. I guess technically( standard ) you are correct.

Comment: Besides: "fresh" malloc() is probably built on mmap /dev/zero, so the memory *will* be initialissed. Setting it to all zeros will cause COW to actually clone and copy the pages anyway.

Comment: @self. I'm no expert on that but the top 3 hits disagree with you: https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=read+uninitialized+variable+undefined+behavior Even if you are correct compilers still treat it as UB (hit 3). The Debian random number generator was crippled because someone thought it was a good idea to mix in an uninitialized variable. Was optimized out.

Comment: @wildplasser the compiler is free to assume otherwise provided that this is in fact UB.

Comment: That may be correct, but the OP specifically mentions gcc and linux. Besides: there are no trap represntations possible for ints (and the ints are never used, only copied) Otherwise reading random dat from an unknown disk file could also cause problems.

Comment: @usr Mr. Google is not an expert either. ;)

Comment: @self. hit 3 explicitly shows that GCC optimized out access to uninitialized variables. UB based benchmarks are very, very dodgy.

Comment: Would be easy to verify : just check the generated assembly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As others already pointed out, Linux uses an [optimistic memory allocation strategy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html#NOTES).

The difference between the first and the following `memcpy`s is the initialization of `DataDest`.

As you have already seen, when you eliminate `memset(DataSrc, 0, N)`, the first `memcpy` is even slower, because the pages for the source must be allocated as well. When you initialize both, `DataSrc` *and* `DataDest`, e.g.

```
memset(DataSrc, 0, N);
memset(DataDest, 0, N);
```

all `memcpy`s will run with roughly the same speed.

For the second question: when you initialize the allocated memory with `memset` all pages will be laid out consecutively. On the other side, when the memory is allocated as you copy, the source and destination pages will be allocated interleaved, which might make the difference.

Comment: Fantastic answer @Olaf Dietsche!

Answer (score 7):

This is most likely due to lazy allocation in your VM subsystem. Typically when you allocate a large amount of memory only the first N pages are actually allocated and wired to physical memory. When you access beyond these first N pages then page faults are generated and further pages are allocated and wired in on an "on demand" basis.

As to the second part of the question, I believe some VM implementations actually track zeroed pages and handle them specially. Try initialising `DataSrc` to actual (e.g. random) values and repeat the test.

Comment: +1 - 'Dirtying' (writing to) all the pages beforehand should indeed make things clear, one may try `calloc()`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1538420/1175253

Comment: @Sam: the top answer on that linked question was incorrect until I fixed it; `calloc` on most mainstream OSes gets zeroed pages from the kernel so they're still lazily allocated and will page-fault on read or write.