# Initialized vs Unitialized value speed test

Tags: c, testing, initialization

I was watching some video where the speed of uninitialized values was greatly emphasized. However, I had watched a different video stating that initialized values are actually faster. I wrote the following test:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void a(int size) {
    int* a = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    memset(a, 0, sizeof(int) * size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    free(a);
}
void b(int size) {
    int* a = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    free(a);
}
int test(void fun(int), int runs, int size) {
    int time = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
        struct timeval beg = {0}, end = {0};
        gettimeofday(&beg, NULL);
        fun(size);
        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
        int usec_diff = end.tv_usec - beg.tv_usec;
        if(usec_diff < 0) {
            time += 1000000;
        } else {
            time += usec_diff;
        }
    }
    return time;
}
int main() {
    int a_3 = test(&a, 100000, 1000);
    int b_3 = test(&b, 100000, 1000);
    printf("b/a ^3: %f\n", (float)b_3 / a_3);
    int a_4 = test(&a, 100000, 10000);
    int b_4 = test(&b, 100000, 10000);
    printf("b/a ^4: %f\n", (float)b_4 / a_4);
    int a_5 = test(&a, 100000, 100000);
    int b_5 = test(&b, 100000, 100000);
    printf("b/a ^5: %f\n", (float)b_5 / a_5);
}
```

I was simply wondering whether this is a good test or not, and whether or not to trust the results. I get the following output:

```
eck@eck:~/src/test$ ./main
b/a ^3: 2.764046
b/a ^4: 0.989866
b/a ^5: 0.990233
```

which seems reasonable, but I wanted to ask since I've never written a test like this before.

Edit: I remembered that you can look at the generated assembly, and I see that with -O1, both functions produce the same assembly. However, I'm not sure if you can do this in a more complex scenario, and would still like clarification on the initialized vs uninitialized thing.

Comment: In general initialising variables always has a (slight) runtime cost. Using an uninitialised variable is always a bad thing and most compilers these days will try to protect you from doing that. However, your sample function code would most likely vanish completely if you used full -O2 optimisation since there is no use of the array or side effect. One way to defeat global optimisers is to have the function under test sum up some loop variable and return it as a result. Even then at the next level out you may need a conditional print statement to stop the most aggressive ones zapping the code!

Comment: You can find some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723215/performance-memset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your measuring method is wrong.

- You measure something very random.
- If you compile with optimizations enabled functions `a` & `b` will be optimized out to the return function:

```
                  b:
0000000000401dd0:   endbr64 
0000000000401dd4:   ret     
                  a:
0000000000401de0:   endbr64 
0000000000401de4:   ret
```

Even if the functions are reduced to the the simple `ret` statement, your code displays nonsense results.

```
b/a ^3: 1.580129
b/a ^4: 0.376331
b/a ^5: 0.378220
```

or

```
b/a ^3: 1.003253
b/a ^4: 1.079337
b/a ^5: 0.243827
```

So you can't measure the execution time this way.

You need also to modify the functions to not be optimized out by the compiler:

```
int *a(size_t size) {
    int* a = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    memset(a, 0, sizeof(int) * size);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    return a;
}
int *b(size_t size) {
    int* a = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    return a;
}
double test(int *fun(size_t), size_t runs, size_t size) {
    clock_t begin = clock();
    int *a;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
        a = fun(size);
        free(a);
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    double time = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    return time;
}
int main() {
    double a_3 = test(&a, 100000ULL, 1000);
    double b_3 = test(&b, 100000ULL, 1000);
    printf("b/a ^3: %f\n", b_3 / a_3);
    double a_4 = test(&a, 100000ULL, 10000);
    double b_4 = test(&b, 100000ULL, 10000);
    printf("b/a ^4: %f\n", b_4 / a_4);
    double a_5 = test(&a, 100000ULL, 100000);
    double b_5 = test(&b, 100000ULL, 100000);
    printf("b/a ^5: %f\n", b_5 / a_5);
}
```

And the results:

```
b/a ^3: 0.760627
b/a ^4: 0.772483
b/a ^5: 0.732345
```

## The conclusion:

Zeroing the memory adds a significant overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer. I noticed my results seemed random, but wasn't sure if this was something to do with uninitialized memory since I've been told to avoid it like the devil.

Comment: @ashton no it was not. Your time measurement method is wrong.