# What does the first "c" stand for in "calloc"?

Tags: c, malloc, libc, calloc, c-standard-library

A student asked the question and I didn't know for sure.

Guesses include: "counted", "clearing", "chunked", "complete", ...

The standard library documentation doesn't say what it stands for and there aren't similarly named functions that would indicate a pattern.  Does anyone know the actual etymology and perhaps have an authoritative reference to back it up?

Comment: Taken from `man 3 calloc`: `void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);` - The  `calloc()` function allocates memory for an array of `nmemb` elements of size bytes each and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.  The memory is set to zero.  If `nmemb` or size is 0, then `calloc()` returns either NULL, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to `free()`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

According to an excerpt from the book [*Linux System Programming*](https://books.google.gr/books?id=LOeK6EZfiH0C&pg=PT467&lpg=PT467&dq=c%20calloc%20etymology&source=bl&ots=HbimNHQqE2&sig=cSfiuKSnEww_Rsjw8NNgHxzL3ww&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBmoVChMIvumwq5-YxwIVgaEUCh3qKwBa#v=onepage&q=c%20calloc%20etymology&f=false) (by Robert Love), no official sources exist on the etymology of `calloc`.

---

Some plausible candidates seem to be:

1. *Count* or *counted*, because `calloc` takes a separate count argument.
2. *Clear*, because it ensures that the returned memory chunk has been cleared.

   - Brian Kernighan is reported to believe that the "c" stands for *clear* (although he has admitted he's not sure).
   - *(See comments.)* An early [`calloc.c`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7/usr/src/libc/gen/calloc.c) seems to contain an explicit reference to the word *clear* in a source code comment (but no reference to the word *count* or to any other candidate). In another source code comment in the file [`malloc.c`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7/usr/src/libc/gen/malloc.c), the word *clear* appears again, in reference to the word `calloc`.
3. *C*, as in the C language.

   - *(See [alk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888422/what-does-the-first-c-stand-for-in-calloc/31906184#31906184) and comments.)* Possibly a naming convention for a set of functions that were introduced at about the same time.

Comment: The V7 (the version that added `malloc()` and `calloc()` to Unix) source code [uses clear in a comment](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7/usr/src/libc/gen/calloc.c) and actually clears the allocated memory block.

Comment: @cremno Wow, that's an extremely useful reference repository. And it probably gets us as close to an answer as we can get. I've edited the answer to include your link.

Comment: And for what then, does the `c` in `cfree()` stand? :-S

Comment: It's in the same original source file (see *cremno*'s comment). So I feel `calloc()` and `cfree()` are definitly related.

Comment: @alk Then maybe a naming convention to match `calloc` (in case `calloc` doesn't use `malloc` in its implementation)?

Comment: If the main purpose of `calloc()` would have been to `clear` out memory, there simply would have been no need for another "freeing"-function. So to turn this around: The existence of `cfree()` can be taken as an evidence, that `calloc()` was thought for some kind of different memory handling then `alloc()`, different besides just `0`ing out the memory.

Comment: @alk If a `calloc` implementation chose to allocate memory in a different way than `malloc` does, it could have a different book-keeping scheme to keep track of the chunks it gives out. In that case, having another counterpart "freeing" function would be reasonable (maybe even necessary). For the cases where `calloc` is implemented by calling `malloc`, `cfree` can just be an alias for `free`. Consider this, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-is-slower-than-calloc

Comment: I feel you should give credits to *Anant Barthwal* as s/he brought up the suggestion of "contiguous" in this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31889465/694576) 1st.

Comment: @alk For the purposes of not overlapping with Anant's answer (which I've also upvoted, as I have your comment in the question), I've instead removed my mention of *contiguous* and rephrased my answer (to not say that these two are the "most" plausible etymologies).

Comment: @cremno: `calloc()` already had been introduce by V6 (http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/source/iolib/calloc.c)

Comment: You might like to have look at my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31906184/694576), if you do not mind.

Comment: @alk: Oh! It's interesting that it doesn't clear the memory (at least explicitly). More interestingly it isn't the only function beginning with `c`. Maybe `c` just stands for C (the programming language) as `open` or `alloc` were already used. See Lesk's [The Portable C Library (on UNIX)](http://www.tom-yam.or.jp/2238/ref/iolib.pdf) which seems to be a document about this `iolib` (doesn't 100% match the V6 one though).

Comment: Another interesting variation I found is `gcalloc()` which in V8 implemented a "*garbage-compacting allocator*": http://man.cat-v.org/unix_8th/9/alloc It also had is own free function: `gcfree()` @cremno

Comment: @cremno If you feel you have found enough clues for the "c" referring to the C language itself, may I suggest you make it an answer? (To me, it sounds like the most convincng etymology right now.)

Comment: contiguous alloc maybe?

Answer (score 9):

I did some research and found the following in ["UNIX@ TIME-SHARING SYSTEM:
UNIX PROGRAMMER'S MANUAL. Seventh Edition, Volume 2", chapter "PROGRAMMING"](http://www.textfiles.com/bitsavers/pdf/att/unix/7th_Edition/UNIX_Programmers_Manual_Seventh_Edition_Vol_2_1983.pdf) (*Italics by me*):

> ```
> char *malloc(num);
> ```
>
> allocates `num` bytes. The pointer returned is sufficiently well aligned to be usable for any purpose. `NULL` is returned if no space is available.
>
> ```
> char *calloc(num, size);
> ```
>
> allocates space for `num` items each of `size` size. The space is guaranteed to be set to 0 and the pointer is sufficiently well aligned to be usable for any purpose. `NULL` is returned if no space is available.
>
> ```
>  cfree(ptr) char *ptr;
> ```
>
> Space is returned to the pool used by `calloc`. *Disorder can be expected if the pointer was not obtained from `calloc`*.

- The last sentence is a clear evidence that `calloc()` was definitely (meant to be?) *more different* from `malloc()` then just by clearing out the memory.

  <sup>Interesting enough there is no reference to `free()` on any of those some hundred pages ... :-)</sup>
- Moreover UNIX V6 already had [`calloc()`](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/source/iolib/calloc.c) which calls [`alloc()`](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/source/iolib/alloc.c). The (linked) source does not show any approach to zero out any memory.

Concluding from the both facts above I strongly object the theory that the leading "c" in `calloc()` stands for "clear".

Comment: Maybe it originally stood for something else but it was definitely re-purposed (like the rest of iolib that became V7's libstdio). I guess it'll be difficult to get a definitive answer (however Mr. Lesk seems to be still alive). Sadly there's already an accepted answer. Btw. what about “count”?

Comment: @cremno: I won't speculate in an answer. In the moment, however I'd tend to bet on "*coalesce*" or "*compact*".

Comment: I don't follow your conclusion about the last sentence of the documentation as being "clear evidence" of anything, except for the fact that it allows an implementation of `calloc` to do something different than `malloc` and zeroing (for example, giving memory from a pre-zeroed source).

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: Did you study the sources for `calloc()`'s V6 implemetation I linked? `free()` returns chunks to the pool with out clearing them. `calloc()` fetches from the pool without clearing anything.

Comment: I am not a reputation-whxxe, I simply did some research, present my results and conclude, what makes sense. @TheodorosChatzigiannakis

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis, and for the "clear evidence": `calloc()`'s V7 implementation calls `malloc()` and after `malloc()` returns `calloc()` clears out the memory. As it calls `malloc()` `free()` could be used, so no need for `cfree()`. But there was a `cfree()` in V7. Why introducing it if there is no need for it, as `free()` would do?

Comment: The way I read it, it seems like the first bullet is a conclusion drawn from the documentation and not from the second bullet. Am I reading your answer correctly in this regard, or not?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: You are right, my two findings are presented in the wrong order, for concluding from top to button. I'll be correcting this now ...

Comment: As I said, `cfree` could be there to allow implementations to use a different book keeping scheme that could be incompatible with `malloc`. Future proofing that proved unnecessary, in other words.

Comment: No need to edit your answer. I only wanted to read your opinion but what about c meaning C as it was originally part of the portable C library (see [this](http://www.tom-yam.or.jp/2238/ref/iolib.pdf) PDF I've linked earlier)? It also supports your first argument.

Comment: Makes sense then, I'm upvoting since your findings are likely to lead us to the correct answer.

Comment: @cremno: With the background of the existence of the "*The Portable C Library (on UNIX)*" having been building in the same stable as UNIX during those days and the fact it introduced the naming convention starting function names with "c"  the idea that the "c" in `calloc()` simply indicates those functions are "C" functions (as opposed to UNIX functions) might be a simple and plausible answer to the OP's question, yes, indeed ... :-)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think anybody knows. But describing the calloc() call with the semantics that the memory must be cleared, as opposed to malloc (memory allocate) which returns any random rubbish that was left over from a previous free() operation, is a useful *modus operandi* for students, which is useful in that it reminds the user that malloc() returns an unsafe value.

Answer (score 3):

`calloc` = contiguous memory allocation.

It means according to syntax of `calloc()` i.e

```
void *calloc (size_t number_of_blocks, size_t size_of_each_block_in_bytes);
```

it receives two parameters: no. of blocks and size of one block, so it allocates an array of memory for the no. of blocks you will provide.

Comment: But `malloc` and `realloc` also allocate a contiguous region of memory. It would be very strange to name something after a property it shares with all other similar things.

Comment: Old topic but to me contiguous makes the most sense as it allocates n chunks of a given size contiguously, whereas `malloc` and `realloc` only allocate one chunk of a given size. You could read `malloc(x)` as "allocate x bytes" and `calloc(n,x)` as "allocate n chunks of x bytes contiguously"

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing.. contiguous sounds right.

Comment: @DavidCallanan Not necessarily. 
"Rather than allocating from a compiled-in fixed-sized array, malloe will
request space from the operating system as needed. Since other activities in the
program may also request space without calling this allocator, the space that
malloe manages may not be contiguous. Thus its free storage is kept as a list
of free blocks. Each block contains a size, a pointer to the next block, and the
space itself."
- Section 8.7 of The C Programming Language, K&R 2nd Ed.

Answer (score 0):

As Anant's answer says, it stands for *Contiguous Allocation*. Per

> Rather than allocating from a compiled-in fixed-sized array, malloe will request space from the operating system as needed. Since other activities in the program may also request space without calling this allocator, the space that malloe manages may not be contiguous. Thus its free storage is kept as a list of free blocks. Each block contains a size, a pointer to the next block, and the space itself. The blocks are kept in order of increasing storage address, and the
> last block (highest address) points to the first.

Section 8.7 of **The C Programming Language**, K&R, *2nd Ed.*

Comment: the heap itself is not contiguous, but blocks of allocated memory separately are **always** contiguous, logically at least