# Uninitialized value was create by a heap allocation if i don't do memset

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, memset

What im interested in is this.

```
char *assign_value = (char*)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
if(strlen(assign_value) == 0) {
    strcpy(assign_value, "A");
} else {
    strcat(assign_value, "A");
}
```

Basically in the example above i will get error that Uninitialized value was create by a heap allocation. But if i do following thing and insert memset() in between malloc() and if statement i wont see same error. I would like to hear some sugestions, is this the right way, if not, what is right thing to do?

```
char *assign_value = (char*)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
memset(assign_value, 0, sizeof(assign_value));
if(strlen(assign_value) == 0) {
    strcpy(assign_value, "A");
} else {
    strcat(assign_value, "A");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `malloc` never initialize or zero it down. If you want you can go with `memset` after it or use `calloc` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from calling `strlen(assign_value)` when `assign_value` is uninitialized, as returned by `malloc(10)`.

Here are three ways to *fix* the problem:

- you can manually set all bytes of the array with `memset(assign_value, 0, 10);`.  Note that your call is incorrect as `sizeof(assign_value)` evaluated to the size of the pointer, not the size of the array.
- you can allocate the array with `calloc(10, sizeof(char))`.  `calloc` returns tha address of a block of memory initialized to all bits zero, which has the same effect as calling `memset`, but is potentially more efficient.
- you can set the initial byte to `'\0'` to make the array an empty string, valid for use with both `strcpy` and `strcat`.

Using `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` is a good habit to avoid unpredictable behavior if you fail to initialize any or all of the allocated data before use.

Note that your code could be simplified radically: if the destination string is indeed empty, calling `strcat()` **is** equivalent to `strcpy()`. You can just write:

```
char *assign_value = calloc(10, sizeof(char));
...
strcat(assign_value, "A");
```

Furthermore, you should verify that `strcat()` will not cause a buffer overflow by checking the length of the string already stored in the buffer:

```
char *assign_value = calloc(10, sizeof(char));
...
if (strlen(assign_value) < 10 - 1) {
    strcat(assign_value, "A");
} else {
    // handle the error: not enough space in assign_value
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i learned something new today. Nice anwser

Answer (score 2):

Yes, memory you get back from `malloc` is uninitialized.  In general, it will contain unpredictable, random values.  By chance the random values *might* be 0 -- but you can't count on this at all.

So, yes, if you care, you must always initialize the memory you get back from `malloc`.  One way is by calling `memset` -- although the example you posted is unusual.  If you want to zero out all the memory you just got back, the usual call would be

```
memset(assign_value, 0, 10);
```

(Instead of `malloc`, you can also use `calloc`.  Once difference between `malloc` and `calloc` is that `calloc` does automatically initialize the newly-allocated memory to all 0.)

If you're using `assign_value` as a string, and you want to have it start out as an empty string, you don't have to zero out all of it.  It's sufficient just to put a null character in the first position:

```
*assign_value = '\0';
```

Once you do any of these things, `assign_value` will hold an empty string, with a length of 0.  So your test `if(strlen(assign_value) == 0)` will always succeed, and in your later code you'll always end up calling `strcpy`, never `strcat`.

Finally, as side points, you don't have to multiply by `sizeof(char)`, or cast the result, when calling `malloc`.  So you could use the simpler:

```
char *assign_value = malloc(10);
```

(You don't have to multiply by `sizeof(char)` because `sizeof(char)` is, by definition, always exactly 1.  You don't have to explicitly cast the result of `malloc` in C, and if you do, it can hide errors.)

Answer (score 0):

`malloc()` allocates memory but does not initialize it.  Whatever happens to be in the memory location allocated, is what you get.
So when using `malloc` it is best to create and initialize the buffer:

```
char *assign_value;
assign_value = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
memset(assign_value, 0, 10);
```

`calloc()` on the other hand allocates memory and initializes all locations allocated to 0:

```
char *assign_value = calloc (10,1);//note sizeof(char) is always 1
```

For more reading, here is a discussion *[comparing malloc() and calloc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538420/difference-between-malloc-and-calloc)*.

Note that it is not necessary to cast the output of [m][c]alloc in C as it is in C++.