# Why is -x[ptr] always 0?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *pi;
    short *ps;

    pi = malloc(16 * sizeof *pi);
    ps = malloc(16 * sizeof *ps);
    pi += 8;
    ps += 8;
    ps = (short*) pi;
    *pi = 1000000;
    printf("*pi = %d,", *pi);
    printf("*ps = %hd\n", *ps);
    printf("before incrementing ps : ps = %p\n", ps);
    ps++;
    printf("after incrementing ps : ps = %p\n", ps);
    printf("*ps = %hd\n", *ps);
    *ps = 16;
    printf("after *ps = %hd -> *pi = %d\n", *ps, *pi);
    printf("ps - 1 = %p, -1 + ps = %p\n", ps - 1,-1 + ps);
    printf("*(ps - 1) = %hd, *(-1 + ps) = %hd\n", *(ps - 1), *(-1 + ps));
    printf("0[ps - 1] = %hd, 1[ps - 2] = %hd, ps[-1] = %hd\n", 0[ps - 1], 1[ps - 2], ps[-1]);
    printf("-1[ps] = %hd, -2[ps + 1] = %hd, -3[ps + 2] = %hd\n", -1[ps], -2[ps + 1], -3[ps + 2]);
    printf("-3[ps] = %hd, -3[ps + 1] = %hd, -3[ps + 3] = %hd,", -3[ps], -3[ps + 1], -3[ps + 3]);
    printf("-3[ps + 4] = %hd\n",-3[ps + 4]);
}
/* format string in printf was adjusted to increase readability */
```

My output:

```
*pi=1000000,*ps=16960
before incrementing ps:ps=0xbb9030
after incrementing ps:ps=0xbb9032
*ps=15
after *ps=16->*pi=1065536
ps-1=0xbb9030,-1+ps=0xbb9030
*(ps-1)=16960,*(-1+ps)=16960
0[ps-1]=16960,1[ps-2]=16960,ps[-1]=16960
-1[ps]=0,-2[ps+1]=0,-3[ps+2]=0
-3[ps]=0,-3[ps+1]=0,-3[ps+3]=0,-3[ps+4]=0
```

I have read that `a[b]` is defined as `*(a+b)`. Therefore, `ps[-1]==*(ps-1)==*(-1+ps)==-1[ps]`. But, as seen in the output, while it is the case that all expressions except the last have the expected value (of `16960`), the last one has the value 0?

Why does this happen? Does -x[ps] produce undefined behavior, causing the compiler to just use 0?

For your information, I use gcc. `gcc -v` outputs `gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5)`.

Comment: Youknowthatthecompilerignoreswhitespaces,don'tyou? This code is too unreadable and too boring to read, please explain your precise problem and try to reproduce it in a simpler program. Also, do you know that `1[x] is the same as x[1]`?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about or what this code is supposed to achieve.

Comment: @EugeneSh. This is a piece of code to experiment with pointer arithmetic.

Comment: This experiment seems to me more about the syntax you can use to perform pointer arithmetics, which is an interesting topic, but you should try to stick to a given syntax, like `x[n]` which is the more readable and intuitive.

Comment: Then isolate the piece of code which is puzzling you and explain the expected and actual behavior.

Comment: `ps[-1]` is the same as `(-1)[ps]`, but `-1[ps]` is `-(1[ps])`, i.e. `-ps[1]`.  You forgot the parentheses.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unary negation `-` has a lower precedence than `[]`.

So `-1[ps]` is evaluated as `-(1[ps])`.

You should also note that pointer arithmetic is only defined within arrays: with the important exceptions that you are allowed to set (though not dereference) a pointer one past the end of an array, or one past the address of a scalar.

Everything else is pretty obvious: particularly you can't access outside the bounds of an array.

Comment: Also, asserting that `-x[ptr]` is always `0` is wrong. Because a simple test could demonstrate that it's not true.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Are you saying that the expressions on the bottom row of the output is zero simply because malloc allocated a piece of memory that was zero? It's very unlikely, as I have run the code multiple times. You can see that even 3[ps + 4] is in the bounds of the array.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Well, I did some more experimenting and found that the array *was*, mysteriously, filled by 0s.

Comment: @user_194421: `malloc` doesn't have to do that. `calloc`, on the other hand, does. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538420/difference-between-malloc-and-calloc

Comment: @Bathsheba But as you can see I used malloc, and I added a piece of code to print the entire malloced memory. It was filled by 0, except the places which I assigned a nonzero value.

Comment: @user_194421: Indeed, but this isn't *standard*. On another platform, or even on yours on a different occasion, the memory buffer might not be zero initialised.

Comment: @Bathsheba I have run the code like *dozens* of times, and it was zeroed. I therefore can conclude that gcc, at least the version I use, zeroes the memory it mallocs. Or can I?

Comment: No you can conclude no such thing. Although it can be sometimes frustratingly difficult to get malloc to give you a non-zeroed buffer. Why not search around the internet for some examples?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156575/discussion-between-user-194421-and-bathsheba).