# Need help understanding np.empty()

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking at `np.empty()` and everywhere it states 'Return a new array of given shape and type, without initializing entries.'

However every time I print `np.empty()` I see it already has random values assigned to it. What am I missing here?

A second question: in case `np.empty()` uses random values, how is it that the below code always returns the same value?

```
print(np.empty((3,2))) 

[[ 1.   5.4]
[ 9.8 14.2]
[18.6 23. ]]
```

Comment: numpy is just grabbing a block of memory without doing anything to the values in there. That's why you see random numbers. I contrast, `np.zeros` grabs a block of memory and assigns all zeros.

Comment: thnk u.. timgeb... why do i get the same values every time though??

Comment: When you see identical values, numpy likely grabbed the same block of memory.

Comment: That's a bad duplicate for this user.  It focuses on an irrelevant detail.

Comment: This is roughly the same difference between [`malloc` and `calloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538420/difference-between-malloc-and-calloc): the latter zero-initializes; the former does not.

Comment: @hpaulj not sure i understand.. you mean duplicate as in duplicate question?

Comment: I was referring to the first link given when this was flagged as a duplicate.  I found a better duplicate (so I think).  In any case, the pattern that you noticed is just an implementation detail.  It's ok to use `np.empty` if you plan on filling ALL elements of the array, otherwise use `np.zeros`, `ones` or `full`.  Another way to put it is - `print(empty([2,2]))` does not tell us anything useful.