# Difference between malloc and calloc in this case?

Tags: c, malloc, calloc

This is a code for multiplying two square matrices in C.

What is the difference between using `malloc` and `calloc` in `void multiply()` function?
When using `malloc`, I am getting garbage values, but `calloc` is providing the right answer.
Only the first row is outputting garbage values so is it an issue with the way `malloc` allocates space in the heap as compared to `calloc`?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *getArray(int);
void display(int *, int, int);
void multiply(int *, int *, int);

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("enter dimension of square matrix:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *arr1;
    int *arr2;
    arr1 = getArray(n);
    display(arr1, n, n);
    printf("\n now give input for next array");
    arr2 = getArray(n);
    display(arr2, n, n);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    multiply(arr1, arr2, n);
    return 0;
}

int *getArray(int n) {
    int *arr = (int *)malloc(n * n * sizeof(int));
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            scanf("%d", (arr + i * n + j));
        }
    }
    /*for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf(" %d ", *(arr + i * n + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }*/
    return arr;
}
    
void display(int *arr, int row, int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            printf(" %d ", *(arr + i * row + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void multiply(int *arr1, int *arr2, int n) {
    int *arr = (int *)calloc(n * n, sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                *(arr + i * n + j) += (*(arr1 + i * n + k)) * (*(arr2 + k * n + j));
            }
        }
    }
    printf("product of above matrices = \n\n");
    display(arr, n, n);
}
```

Comment: Using `malloc()`, the allocated memory is not initialized; using `calloc()`, the allocated memory is initialized to all bytes zero.

Comment: In your case there is no functional difference as you initialize the memory. But using `calloc` here means unnecessary setting to zero by `calloc`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between malloc and calloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538420/difference-between-malloc-and-calloc)

Comment: `calloc(n*n,sizeof(int)` does not overflow the size calculation as readily as `malloc(n*n*sizeof(int))`.  Better to use `malloc(sizeof(int)*n*n*)` with `malloc()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: actually both calls pose problems if `n * n` exceeds the range of type `int`, they just fail in different ways. `malloc(sizeof(int) * n * n)` is definitely better and `calloc((size_t)n * n, sizeof(int))` is advisable too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only functional difference between allocating memory with `malloc()` and with `calloc()` for the same size, assuming the size computation is accurate, is the latter initializes the block to all bits 0, whereas the former does not.

All bits 0 means all `int` values in the array are initialized to `0`.

The inner loop in the `multiply` function only increments the element at row `i` and column `j`, therefore the function relies on implicit initialization of the array elements to 0. `calloc()` does that, but not `malloc()` so you definitely need to use `calloc()`.

Also note these remarks:

- in `display` the computation for the offset of the matrix element at row `i` column `j` should be `printf(" %5d ", *(arr + i * col + j));`
- `multiply` should return `arr` and `display()` should be called in the `main` function.
- you should check for `scanf()`, `malloc() and` calloc()` failure
- you should free allocated memory
- pointer arguments to objects that are not modified by the function should be `const` qualified so the function can be called with a pointer to a `const` object.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *getArray(int);
void display(const int *, int, int);
int *multiply(const int *, const int *, int);

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("enter dimension of square matrix:\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;
    printf("\n now give input for the first array");
    int *arr1 = getArray(n);
    if (!arr1)
        return 1;
    display(arr1, n, n);
    printf("\n now give input for the second array");
    int *arr2 = getArray(n);
    if (!arr2)
        return 1;
    display(arr2, n, n);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    int *arr = multiply(arr1, arr2, n);
    if (!arr)
        return 1;
    printf("product of above matrices = \n\n");
    display(arr, n, n);
    free(arr1);
    free(arr2);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}

int *getArray(int n) {
    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * n * n);
    if (arr == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (scanf("%d", (arr + i * n + j)) != 1) {
                free(arr);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
    
void display(const int *arr, int row, int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            printf(" %5d ", *(arr + i * col + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int *multiply(const int *arr1, const int *arr2, int n) {
    int *arr = calloc((size_t)n * n, sizeof(int));
    if (arr == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                *(arr + i * n + j) += (*(arr1 + i * n + k)) * (*(arr2 + k * n + j));
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: what is the role of using const? also, thank you @chqrlie for the answer.

Comment: @SiddharthKolipara: in a function definition, pointer arguments to objects that are not modified by the function should be `const` qualified so the function can be called with a pointer to a `const` object. For example `strcpy()` is declared as `char *strcpy(char *s1, const char *s2);` because the contents of the array pointed to by `s2` are not modified, but the destination array pointed to by `s1` is, and is returned.