# Infinite while-loop while printing nodes in linkedlist

Tags: c, linked-list

If I call createnode(x) in main and then follow that with printNodes(); I will get an infinite while-loop that seems to be printing some memory address. I am guessing the issue lies in the fact that i set head = temp?

```
SinglyLinkedList *head = NULL;

void createNode(int data){
    SinglyLinkedList *temp = malloc(sizeof(SinglyLinkedList));
    temp-> data = data;

    if(head == NULL){
        head = temp;
        return;
    }

    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}

void printNodes(){

    SinglyLinkedList *temp = head;

    while ( temp != NULL ){
        printf("%d\r\n",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

}
```

Comment: You only give a value to `temp->next` when `head` is not NULL.  To be correct, the code must always set `temp->next`. The easy way to do that is to remove the whole `if` statement.

Comment: Try using `calloc` instead?

Comment: @user3386109 I totally forgot that I didn't set `temp->next`, it fixed the problem instantly.. thanks! :)

Comment: next time please make sure you add the *complete* code (including the definition of `SingleLinkedList` and a minimal `main`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between malloc and calloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538420/difference-between-malloc-and-calloc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```c
SinglyLinkedList *temp = malloc(sizeof(SinglyLinkedList));
temp->data = data;

if(head == NULL){
    head = temp;
    return;
}

temp->next = head;
head = temp;
```

should be

```c
SinglyLinkedList *temp = malloc(sizeof(SinglyLinkedList));
temp->data = data;
temp->next = head;    // Moved

if(head == NULL){
    head = temp;
    return;
}

head = temp;
```

which is a very complicate way of writing

```c
SinglyLinkedList *temp = malloc(sizeof(SinglyLinkedList));
temp->data = data;
temp->next = head;
head = temp;
```

Without this fix, `printNodes` results in undefined behaviour as a result of the lack of initialization of `temp->next`.