# Shared memory marked as virtual memory?

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system, ipc

I run a program which allocates 64MB as shared memory for IPC communication. pmap shows that chunk of 64MB is allocated. However, "top" shows the RES memory of the proc is just about 40MB! I conclude the shared memory is marked as VIRT. But why? There Linux still has more than 1GB RAM available.

Comment: Does it *use* all 64MB immediately?

Comment: In linux, unless you are the kernel, or you are dealing with something like a hardware-mapped frame buffer or something, pretty much all memory is virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually used any of that 64MB yet?  Linux defers allocation.

cf. [Does malloc lazily create the backing pages for an allocation on Linux (and other platforms)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911860/does-malloc-lazily-create-the-backing-pages-for-an-allocation-on-linux-and-othe)

Comment: Your theory looks right! I just ran a test, letting this app receiving messages using the chunk of shared memory, and observed the RES increases substantially, and VIRT remains almost the same.

Comment: Its actually a very helpful feature when apps pre-allocate vast amounts of memory they'll never actually.

Comment: Whether the OS uses lazy allocation or not is unrelated to what the OP observes here. That would be exactly the same with OSes not doing lazy allocation like Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

Linux doesn't load all memory the process "obtain" to RAM , it load memory form virtual place to RAM just when you program refer that block of memory. Here "memory" means private mem &　shared mem both.
I　haven't done any experiments to verify the above opinion, but I have seen this in many places like SO, and I do believe it . Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Shared memory is, just like most if not all of the memory userland programs deal with, virtual. Only active pages need to be mapped to physical (i.e. resident memory). Doing differently would be a waste of resources.

The only exception is when the process specifically locks the pages in RAM with `mlock`.