# No output while doing try catch in c++

Tags: c++, try-catch, bad-alloc

I am trying to catch bad allocation error. When input length will be in order of 10000000000000000000000 or something, then bad allocation error should come. I don't know why its not being caught. 
Any help will be appreciated!

```
# include <vector>
# include <iostream>


using namespace std;

void length(int m)
{
    vector<int> x;

    try
    {
    x.resize(m);
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc&) 
    {
        cout << "caught bad alloc exception" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()

{

    int l;
    cout << "Length" ;
    cin >> l ;
    length(l);

    return 0;
}
```

*UPDATED:*

When I am hard coding the value for input, then it is throwing an exception. I don't know why its working this way.

```
# include <vector>
# include <iostream>


using namespace std;



void length(int m)
{
    vector<int> x;

    try
    {
    x.resize(m);
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc&) 
    {
        cout << "caught bad alloc exception" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()

{

    int m= 100000000000000000000;
    length(m);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see the caught exception [running here](http://cpp.sh/9fwg) with a large input (e.g. 10000000000)

Comment: Can it be a compiler issue? Because I am not getting this exception.

Comment: How do you input `2^500` for this?

Comment: @m0nhawk I was just referring to a very large number.

Comment: Just FYI on maximum size: [Related: Is there a max array length limit in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/216266/1030110)

Comment: Note that `std::size_t` has a maximum value. If you try to request a vector with more than that number of elements, you will not actually be trying to allocate that many elements.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864416/are-some-allocators-lazy)?

Comment: [Pro tip] When you think it is right but it is not, outputting the variable to check what the program received is a useful debugging tool.

Comment: @jennifer Why not hard-code the value you claim should throw an exception, instead of the input hiding behind a `cin` statement?  Then everyone will see what value you are trying instead of guessing.

Answer (score 1):

You ought to write

```
if (!(cin >> l)){
    // I could not read that into `l`
}
```

The lack of an exception being caught could be down to

1. Your `int` value being smaller than you think (perhaps some *undefined* wrap-around behaviour), and an exception is not thrown since the allocation is successful.
2. The allocation being *lazy* in the sense that the memory is not allocated until you actually use it.
3. If `std::bad_alloc` is thrown as an *anonymous temporary* then it will not be caught at your catch site. (Unless your naughty compiler allows non-`const` references to bind to anonymous temporaries, which some do as an extension). Write `catch (const std::bad_alloc&)` instead, and it *will* be caught there.

Comment: While correct in terms of how to capture the application should terminate with an uncaught exception if the exception was not caught.  That is not happening so no exception is being thrown.

Comment: Well this *proves* that `std::bad_alloc` is *not* being thrown.

Comment: Indeed, but the OP has an `int` for `l`.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum length of an integer type int is 2.147.483.647 . Are you sure you have actually used an higher number to test it?

Comment: The maximum size of an `int` is undefined.  All we know for sure is that it must be at least 32767.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Prefer "implementation defined" to "undefined"?

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes.  I misspoke there.  It is implementation defined.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're passing Integer variable which has the limit.
       Minimum value for a variable of type short: –32768
       Maximum value for a variable of type short:  32767
2. The error which you will get from your code is **std::length_error**
3. To raise the bad allocation error dynamically you can try **malloc**() with incorrect size OR try below code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

int main()
{
    try {
        while (true) {
            new int[100000000ul];
        }
    } catch (const std::bad_alloc& e) {
        std::cout << "Allocation failed: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
</i>
```

Comment: Actually it's -32767, for a `short` *and* an `int`. Don't forget 1's complement and signed magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

No exception is thrown because the `int` that makes it through to your function `void length(int m)` is capped at its max value that is much less than  `vector::max_size()`. Consider:

```
void length(int m)
{
    cout << "m is: " << m << " which has a max value: " << numeric_limits<int>::max() <<  endl;
    // ...
}
```

with the output:
`Length10000000000000000000000
m is: 2147483647 and has a max value: 2147483647`